# What is the simplest way to find the difference between 2 times in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have 2 time values which have the type `datetime.time`. I want to find their difference. The obvious thing to do is t1 - t2, but this doesn't work. It works for objects of type `datetime.datetime` but not for `datetime.time`. So what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, note that a datetime.time is a time of day, independent of a given day, and so the different between any two datetime.time values is going to be less than 24 hours.

One approach is to convert both datetime.time values into comparable values (such as milliseconds), and find the difference.

```
t1, t2 = datetime.time(...), datetime.time(...)

t1_ms = (t1.hour*60*60 + t1.minute*60 + t1.second)*1000 + t1.microsecond
t2_ms = (t2.hour*60*60 + t2.minute*60 + t2.second)*1000 + t2.microsecond

delta_ms = max([t1_ms, t2_ms]) - min([t1_ms, t2_ms])
```

It's a little lame, but it works.

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't preserve sign. Also,
delta_ms = abs(t1_ms - t2_ms) is a little easier to understand and saves at least a subtraction.

Comment: doesn't work if t1_ms is before midnight and t2_ms is after midnight

Comment: Shouldn't it be * 1000000? Since 1 s = 1000000 µs.

Answer (score 16):

Also a little silly, but you could try picking an arbitrary day and embedding each time in it, using `datetime.datetime.combine`, then subtracting:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t1 = datetime.time(2,3,4)
>>> t2 = datetime.time(18,20,59)
>>> dummydate = datetime.date(2000,1,1)
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(dummydate,t2) - datetime.datetime.combine(dummydate,t1)
datetime.timedelta(0, 58675)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could transform both into [timedelta objects](http://docs.python.org/lib/datetime-timedelta.html) and subtract these from each other, which will take care to of the carry-overs. For example:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> t1 = dt.time(23, 5, 5, 5)
>>> t2 = dt.time(10, 5, 5, 5)
>>> dt1 = dt.timedelta(hours=t1.hour, minutes=t1.minute, seconds=t1.second, microseconds=t1.microsecond)
>>> dt2 = dt.timedelta(hours=t2.hour, minutes=t2.minute, seconds=t2.second, microseconds=t2.microsecond)
>>>  print(dt1-dt2)
13:00:00
>>> print(dt2-dt1)
-1 day, 11:00:00
>>> print(abs(dt2-dt1))
13:00:00
```

Negative timedelta objects in Python get a negative day field, with the other fields positive. You could check beforehand: comparison works on both time objects and timedelta objects:

```
>>> dt2 < dt1
True
>>> t2 < t1
True
```

Comment: chryss: You could seriously do well with an example here.

Answer (score 3):

Python has pytz (http://pytz.sourceforge.net) module which can be used for arithmetic of 'time' objects. It takes care of DST offsets as well. The above page has a number of examples that illustrate the usage of pytz.

Comment: it does not make sense to talk about timezones knowing only time without specifying a *date* too. If you know both date and time then [multiple defintions for a difference may be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427822/4279)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this isn't supported, since there wouldn't be a good way to deal with overflows in datetime.time.  I know this isn't an answer directly, but maybe someone with more python experience than me can take this a little further.  For more info, see this: http://bugs.python.org/issue3250

Answer (score -1):

Retrieve the times in milliseconds and then do the subtraction.

Answer (score -3):

Environment.TickCount seems to work well if you need something quick.

int start = Environment.TickCount

...DoSomething()

int elapsedtime = Environment.TickCount - start

Jon