# How to subtract a day from a date?

Tags: python, date, datetime, timedelta

I have a Python [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object. What is the best way to subtract one day?

Comment: related: [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Comment: This thread is directly useful to convert a day of the year to a date.

Answer (score 1991, accepted):

You can use a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    
d = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
```

Comment: if you don't ignore timezones then [the answer is more complex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427822/4279).

Comment: Also, how do you relate it with a specific date. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092508/first-available-date-previous-day-month-year

Comment: It works with other units as well, I've used it with `timedelta(minutes=12)` for example.

Comment: the documentation says that will return _"A duration expressing the difference between two date, time, or datetime instances..."._ how do you get the actual date of, say, 5 days ago or 5 days from now?

Comment: @jfs I think this answer is fine in regard to time zones. If you subtract a day, that *might* actually subtract 23 or 25 hours, but the time component will remain the same.  That's what I would expect as normal behavior. Daylight saving time (DST) makes so that 1 day is not always 24 hours.

Comment: @at54321: whether exactly 24hours required or whether having the exact same clock time (hours) is preferable may depend on the task. [My answer covers both cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25427822/4279)

Answer (score 107):

Subtract `datetime.timedelta(days=1)`

Answer (score 97):

If your Python datetime object is timezone-aware than you should be careful to avoid errors around DST transitions (or changes in UTC offset for other reasons):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from tzlocal import get_localzone # pip install tzlocal

DAY = timedelta(1)
local_tz = get_localzone()   # get local timezone
now = datetime.now(local_tz) # get timezone-aware datetime object
day_ago = local_tz.normalize(now - DAY) # exactly 24 hours ago, time may differ
naive = now.replace(tzinfo=None) - DAY # same time
yesterday = local_tz.localize(naive, is_dst=None) # but elapsed hours may differ
```

In general, `day_ago` and `yesterday` may differ if UTC offset for the local timezone has changed in the last day.

For example,  daylight saving time/summer time ends on Sun 2-Nov-2014 at 02:00:00 A.M. in America/Los_Angeles timezone therefore if:

```
import pytz # pip install pytz

local_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
now = local_tz.localize(datetime(2014, 11, 2, 10), is_dst=None)
# 2014-11-02 10:00:00 PST-0800
```

then `day_ago` and `yesterday` differ:

- `day_ago` is exactly 24 hours ago (relative to `now`) but at 11 am, not at 10 am as `now`
- `yesterday` is yesterday at 10 am but it is 25 hours ago (relative to `now`), not 24 hours.

---

[`pendulum` module](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) handles it automatically:

```
>>> import pendulum  # $ pip install pendulum

>>> now = pendulum.create(2014, 11, 2, 10, tz='America/Los_Angeles')
>>> day_ago = now.subtract(hours=24)  # exactly 24 hours ago
>>> yesterday = now.subtract(days=1)  # yesterday at 10 am but it is 25 hours ago

>>> (now - day_ago).in_hours()
24
>>> (now - yesterday).in_hours()
25

>>> now
<Pendulum [2014-11-02T10:00:00-08:00]>
>>> day_ago
<Pendulum [2014-11-01T11:00:00-07:00]>
>>> yesterday
<Pendulum [2014-11-01T10:00:00-07:00]>
```

Answer (score 54):

Just to Elaborate **an alternate method** and a Use case for which it is helpful:

- Subtract 1 day from current datetime:

> ```
> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
> print datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-1)  # Here, I am adding a negative timedelta
> ```

- **Useful in the Case**, If you want to add 5 days and subtract 5 hours from current datetime. i.e. What is the Datetime 5 days from now but 5 hours less ?

> ```
> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
> print datetime.now() + timedelta(days=5, hours=-5)
> ```

It can similarly be used with other parameters e.g. seconds, weeks etc

Answer (score 16):

Also just another nice function i like to use when i want to compute i.e. first/last day of the last month or other relative timedeltas etc. ...

The relativedelta function from [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) function (a powerful extension to the datetime lib)

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
#get first and last day of this and last month)
today = dt.date.today()
first_day_this_month = dt.date(day=1, month=today.month, year=today.year)
last_day_last_month = first_day_this_month - relativedelta(days=1)
print (first_day_this_month, last_day_last_month)

>2015-03-01 2015-02-28
```

Answer (score 9):

Genial arrow module exists

```
import arrow
utc = arrow.utcnow()
utc_yesterday = utc.shift(days=-1)
print(utc, '\n', utc_yesterday)
```

output:

```
2017-04-06T11:17:34.431397+00:00 
 2017-04-05T11:17:34.431397+00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use pandas `pd.Timedelta('1D')` (it's extremely flexible and you can even pass something like `pd.Timedelta('1d 5h 9s')` for 1 day, 5 hours and 9 seconds).

A convenient thing about pandas is that its datetime objects are built on `datetime.datetime`, so any operation involving Python's `datetime` objects work fine on pandas datetime objects and vice versa.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

datetime.now() - pd.Timedelta('1d')           # datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 21, 15, 35, 23, 603832)
pd.Timestamp('now') - timedelta(days=1)       # Timestamp('2023-02-21 15:35:23.741866')
pd.Timestamp('now') - pd.Timedelta('1d')      # Timestamp('2023-02-21 15:35:23.882746')
pd.Timestamp('now') - np.timedelta64(1, 'D')  # Timestamp('2023-02-21 15:35:24.032356')

date(2022, 2, 22) - pd.Timedelta('10d')        # datetime.date(2022, 2, 12)
```

The advantage of pandas is that you can perform vectorized operations (even if the dtype is object). You can use either of `pd.Timedelta`/`datetime.timedelta`/`np.timedelta64`.

```py
pd.Series([datetime(2023,2,22), datetime(2023,2,21), datetime(2023,2,20)]) - pd.Timedelta('1d')
pd.Series([date(2023,2,22), date(2023,2,21), date(2023,2,20)]) - timedelta(days=1)
pd.Series([date(2023,2,22), date(2023,2,21), date(2023,2,20)]) - np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

Answer (score -15):

```
class myDate:

    def __init__(self):
        self.day = 0
        self.month = 0
        self.year = 0
        ## for checking valid days month and year
        while (True):
            d = int(input("Enter The day :- "))
            if (d > 31):
                print("Plz 1 To 30 value Enter ........")
            else:
                self.day = d
                break

        while (True):
            m = int(input("Enter The Month :- "))
            if (m > 13):
                print("Plz 1 To 12 value Enter ........")
            else:
                self.month = m
                break

        while (True):
            y = int(input("Enter The Year :- "))
            if (y > 9999 and y < 0000):
                print("Plz 0000 To 9999 value Enter ........")
            else:
                self.year = y
                break
    ## method for aday ands cnttract days
    def adayDays(self, n):
        ## aday days to date day
        nd = self.day + n
        print(nd)
        ## check days subtract from date
        if nd == 0: ## check if days are 7  subtracted from 7 then,........
            if(self.year % 4 == 0):
                if(self.month == 3):
                    self.day = 29
                    self.month -= 1
                    self.year = self. year
            else:
                if(self.month == 3):
                    self.day = 28
                    self.month -= 1
                    self.year = self. year
            if  (self.month == 5) or (self.month == 7) or (self.month == 8) or (self.month == 10) or (self.month == 12):
                self.day = 30
                self.month -= 1
                self.year = self. year
                   
            elif (self.month == 2) or (self.month == 4) or (self.month == 6) or (self.month == 9) or (self.month == 11):
                self.day = 31
                self.month -= 1
                self.year = self. year

            elif(self.month == 1):
                self.month = 12
                self.year -= 1    
        ## nd == 0 if condition over
        ## after subtract days to day io goes into negative then
        elif nd < 0 :   
            n = abs(n)## return positive if no is negative
            for i in range (n,0,-1): ## 
                
                if self.day == 0:

                    if self.month == 1:
                        self.day = 30
                        
                        self.month = 12
                        self.year -= 1
                    else:
                        self.month -= 1
                        if(self.month == 1) or (self.month == 3)or (self.month == 5) or (self.month == 7) or (self.month == 8) or (self.month == 10) or (self.month ==12):
                            self.day = 30
                        elif(self.month == 4)or (self.month == 6) or (self.month == 9) or (self.month == 11):
                            self.day = 29
                        elif(self.month == 2):
                            if(self.year % 4 == 0):
                                self.day == 28
                            else:
                                self.day == 27
                else:
                    self.day -= 1

        ## enf of elif negative days
        ## adaying days to DATE
        else:
            cnt = 0
            while (True):

                if self.month == 2:  # check leap year
                    
                    if(self.year % 4 == 0):
                        if(nd > 29):
                            cnt = nd - 29
                            nd = cnt
                            self.month += 1
                        else:
                            self.day = nd
                            break
                ## if not leap year then
                    else:  
                    
                        if(nd > 28):
                            cnt = nd - 28
                            nd = cnt
                            self.month += 1
                        else:
                            self.day = nd
                            break
                ## checking month other than february month
                elif(self.month == 1) or (self.month == 3) or (self.month == 5) or (self.month == 7) or (self.month == 8) or (self.month == 10) or (self.month == 12):
                    if(nd > 31):
                        cnt = nd - 31
                        nd = cnt

                        if(self.month == 12):
                            self.month = 1
                            self.year += 1
                        else:
                            self.month += 1
                    else:
                        self.day = nd
                        break

                elif(self.month == 4) or (self.month == 6) or (self.month == 9) or (self.month == 11):
                    if(nd > 30):
                        cnt = nd - 30
                        nd = cnt
                        self.month += 1

                    else:
                        self.day = nd
                        break
                ## end of month condition
        ## end of while loop
    ## end of else condition for adaying days
    def formatDate(self,frmt):

        if(frmt == 1):
            ff=str(self.day)+"-"+str(self.month)+"-"+str(self.year)
        elif(frmt == 2):
            ff=str(self.month)+"-"+str(self.day)+"-"+str(self.year)
        elif(frmt == 3):
            ff =str(self.year),"-",str(self.month),"-",str(self.day)
        elif(frmt == 0):
            print("Thanky You.....................")
            
        else:
            print("Enter Correct Choice.......")
        print(ff)
            
            

dt = myDate()
nday = int(input("Enter No. For Aday or SUBTRACT Days :: "))
dt.adayDays(nday)
print("1 : day-month-year")
print("2 : month-day-year")
print("3 : year-month-day")
print("0 : EXIT")
frmt = int (input("Enter Your Choice :: "))
dt.formatDate(frmt)

    enter code here
```

Comment: It is better to use the standard library when possible, cause it is usually maintained by a lot of people, has little errors and performs faster

Comment: DateTime lib do the work in here :) no need for special logic