# Python time to age

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a date string into an age.

The string is like: "Mon, 17 Nov 2008 01:45:32 +0200" and I need to work out how many days old it is.

I have sucessfully converted the date using:

```
>>> time.strptime("Mon, 17 Nov 2008 01:45:32 +0200","%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0200")
(2008, 11, 17, 1, 45, 32, 0, 322, -1)
```

For some reason %z gives me an error for the +0200 but it doesn't matter that much.

I can get the current time using:

```
>>> time.localtime()
(2009, 2, 3, 19, 55, 32, 1, 34, 0)
```

but how can I subtract one from the other without going though each item in the list and doing it manually?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the module `datetime` and the object [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

```
from datetime import datetime

t1 = datetime.strptime("Mon, 17 Nov 2008 01:45:32 +0200","%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0200")
t2 = datetime.now()

tdelta = t2 - t1 # actually a datetime.timedelta object
print tdelta.days
```

Comment: The code snippet is incorrect.  You need to import 'datetime' from datetime, not date (or use the date object, rather than the datetime object).

Comment: The result is incorrect if input date string is not in the local timezone. You need [an aware datetime object as in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25426694/4279) instead or some other way to track given UTC offset e.g., [`email.utils.parsedate_tz()`-based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/510638/4279).
 Also,
`tdelta.days` may give a surprising result e.g.,
`timedelta(seconds=-5).days == -1`; `tdelta / timedelta(1)` could be
used instead (or its analog on older Python versions:
`timedelta(seconds=-5).total_seconds() / 86400`).

Comment: the result may be also wrong if `t1` and `t2` have different UTC offsets e.g., if `t1` is a standard time and `t2` is a summer time (`is_dst=1`) -- see [what may happen if `t1` and `t2` are on the opposite sides of DST transition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427822/4279).

Answer (score 5):

In Python, `datetime` objects natively support subtraction:

```
from datetime import datetime
age = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(...)
print age.days
```

The result is a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

Comment: [The result is incorrect if input date string is not in the local timezone.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508727/python-time-to-age/25426694#comment39666382_508742)

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 3, 15, 17, 35, 156000)
datetime.now() - datetime(1984, 6, 29 )
datetime.timedelta(8985, 55091, 206000)
datetime.now() - datetime(1984, 6, 29 )
datetime.timedelta(8985, 55094, 198000) # my age...
```

timedelta(days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use datetime (e.g. if your Python is old and you don't have the module), you can just use the time module.

```
s = "Mon, 17 Nov 2008 01:45:32 +0200"
import time
import email.utils # Using email.utils means we can handle the timezone.
t = email.utils.parsedate_tz(s) # Gets the time.mktime 9-tuple, plus tz
d = time.time() - time.mktime(t[:9]) + t[9] # Gives the difference in seconds.
```

Comment: +1 for parsedate_tz. Though your code produces a wrong result due to `+ t[9]`, [use mktime_tz() as in my answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25426694/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I ended up with the following:

```
def getAge( d ):
    """ Calculate age from date """
    delta = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(d, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0200")
    return delta.days + delta.seconds / 86400.0 # divide secs into days
```

Giving:

```
>>> getAge("Mon, 17 Nov 2008 01:45:32 +0200")
78.801319444444445
```

Comment: That isn't guaranteed to be correct because of leap years (and seconds).

Comment: The datetime module knows about leap years.  It may well also know about leap seconds also, but that hardly seems relevant when the OP is concerned about time in days.

Comment: It looks like he's concerned about time in years.

Comment: The function returns number of days.
Its not vital that it is super accurate for what I need.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.2, `datetime.strptime()` returns an aware datetime object if `%z` directive is provided:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

s = "Mon, 17 Nov 2008 01:45:32 +0200"
birthday = datetime.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
age = (datetime.now(timezone.utc) - birthday) / timedelta(1) # age in days
print("%.0f" % age)
```

On older Python versions the correct version of [@Tony Meyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510638/4279) could be used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz

s = "Mon, 17 Nov 2008 01:45:32 +0200"
ts = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(s))   # seconds since Epoch
age = (time.time() - ts) / 86400  # age in days
print("%.0f" % age)
```

Both code examples produce the same result.