# Parsing an ISO datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting string to datetime object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609259/converting-string-to-datetime-object-in-python)

Given the below Python

```
import datetime

>>> a
'2011-05-04 16:20:09 -0700'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
>>>
```

I don't really understand how `%z` is a bad directive.

Reference:
http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

This is from hg, which says that it is in ISO8601 format.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526406/python-time-to-age-part-2-timezones

Answer (score 7):

Here is the complete story:

http://bugs.python.org/issue6641

and related:

[Converting string with UTC offset to a datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609259/converting-string-to-datetime-object-in-python)