# use type() information to cast values stored as strings

Tags: python, casting, data-conversion, built-in-types

In my application I have generated a number of values (three columns, of type int, str and datetime, see example below) and these values are stored in a flat file as comma-separated strings. Furthermore, I store a file containing the type of the values (see below). Now, how can I use this information to cast my values from the flat file to the correct data type in Python? Is is possible or do I need to do some other stuff?

Data file:

```
#id,value,date
1,a,2011-09-13 15:00:00
2,b,2011-09-13 15:10:00
3,c,2011-09-13 15:20:00
4,d,2011-09-13 15:30:00
```

Type file:

```
id,<type 'int'>
value,<type 'str'>
date,<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, you already parsed the file, you now just need to get the right type. So let's say `id_`, `type_` and `value` are three strings that contain the values in the file. (Note, `type_` should contain `'int'` — for example —, not `'<type 'int'>'`.

```
def convert(value, type_):
    import importlib
    try:
        # Check if it's a builtin type
        module = importlib.import_module('__builtin__')
        cls = getattr(module, type_)
    except AttributeError:
        # if not, separate module and class
        module, type_ = type_.rsplit(".", 1)
        module = importlib.import_module(module)
        cls = getattr(module, type_)
    return cls(value)
```

Then you can use it like..:

```
value = convert("5", "int")
```

Unfortunately for datetime this doesnt work though, as it can not be simply initialized by its string representation.

Comment: While this **does** correctly answer the question, it's a really bad approach.  It has numerous limitations.  For example, it's limited to default, single-argument conversions.  Changing the datetime format, for example, leads to creating a closure with the format string that can then be applied to the input.  This rapidly devolves into fairly complex code so that `getattr()` and `cls()` can be forced to work even when there are simpler alternatives.

Comment: "type" shouldn't be called that

Comment: By the way, it might be useful to specify that to obtain 'int' instead of <type 'int'> from type(a) (supposing a is a variable of type int), you can do type(a).__name__. However, for types such as <type 'numpy.float64'>, it will return 'float64' and not 'numpy.float64'. Thus, depending on the situation, you might also use str(type(anObject)).split("'")[1].

Answer (score 2):

Your types file can be simpler:

```
id=int
value=str
date=datetime.datetime
```

Then in your main program you can

```
import datetime

def convert_datetime(text):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(text, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

data_types = {'int':int, 'str':str, 'datetime.datetime':convert_datetime}
fields = {}

for line in open('example_types.txt').readlines():
    key, val = line.strip().split('=')
    fields[key] = val

data_file = open('actual_data.txt')
field_info = data_file.readline().strip('#\n ').split(',')
values = [] #store it all here for now

for line in data_file.readlines():
    row = []
    for i, element in enumerate(line.strip().split(',')):
        element_type = fields[field_info[i]] # will get 'int', 'str', or 'datetime'
        convert = data_types[element_type]
        row.append(convert(element))
    values.append(row)

# to show it working...
for row in values:
    print row
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Read the file line by line, for each line do the following steps
2. Split the line using `split()` with `,` as the separator.
3. Cast the first element of list (from step 2) as an int. Keep the second element as string. Parse the third value `(e.g. using slices)` and make a `datetime` object of the same.

Comment: hi, the reading, splitting etc. is done. I'm trying to implement a generic type convert, using the information in the type file. In general I have no idea what types the columns are, this is what the type file must tell me at runtime!

Comment: Ohk! Then you just need to parse the type file and store it in some data-structure so that you get the structure of the file. After that, you can parse the data file as required (but I think you'll need to do something for the `datetime` type). Also, a generic type convert means built-in types or any user-defined types too? If user-defined types are also to be supported, it is gonna take a hell lot of programming. :)

Comment: yeah, i have done that, but the big question is still, how do i get e.g. datetime.datetime object from my string '2011-09-13 15:00:00' at runtime (these types could also be Decimal, float etc.) i cant just use simple string matching e.g.: tmp_type == 'float': return float(val)

Comment: a simple regex might be helpful to you for the same... maybe you could check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307176/best-way-to-extract-datetime-from-string-in-python when your type-file tells you that you need to parse a date-time object.

Comment: regex is not good enough, it could be the case that my string column is actually a list of integers, but must be treated as strings in Python... Therefor, the type file, must determine all types!

Comment: but your type file will not let that happen! if your type file says that the next thing is a list of integers, how can you treat it as a string?

Comment: like others are saying, I would also recommend you to use `pickle`... no use in `reinventing the wheel`...

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with a similar situation in a recent program, that had to convert many fields. I used a list of tuples, where one element of the tuples was the conversion function to use. Sometimes it was `int` or `float`; sometimes it was a simple `lambda`; and sometimes it was the name of a function defined elsewhere.

Comment: See OP's comment to your answer. OP has done the splitting and needs to convert the data. My answer addresses that. For the simple things, you use `int` and such. For the complex things like the `datetime`, you want a function. Using a list of fields like this lets you do this in a structured way.

Comment: I have had my mind on convertion functions, but i would like to have a more generic approach. I am thinking of an 'serialization' like approach if it is possible in Python!

Comment: That's ok, we all act hastily sometimes. Thanks for the undo.

Comment: It sounds more like you're trying to **de**serialize?

Comment: Serialization? Why don't you then use pickle then? If there's no strict requirement for dumping in human-readable comma-separated list, use pickle.

Comment: Tom -> yeah, it is de-serialize that is my problem :) "\n" c0Da -> it is not possible to change the data source is it is flat files - but the content of the type file can be extende to what ever is needed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a separate "type" file, take your list of tuples of `(id, value, date)` and just [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) it.

Or you'll have to solve the problem of storing your string-to-type converters as text (in your "type" file), which might be a fun problem to solve, but if you're just trying to get something done, go with [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) or [`cPickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot write a "universal" or "smart" conversion that magically handles anything.

Second, trying to summarize a string-to-data conversion in anything other than code never seems to work out well.  So rather than write a string that names the conversion, just write the conversion.

Finally, trying to write a configuration file in a domain-specific language is silly.  Just write Python code.  It's not much more complicated than trying to parse some configuration file.

> Is is possible or do i need to do some other stuff?

Don't waste time trying to create a "type file" that's not simply Python.  It doesn't help.  It is simpler to write the conversion as a Python function.  You can import that function as if it was your "type file".

```
import datetime

def convert( row ):
   return dict(
       id= int(row['id']),
       value= str(row['value']),
       date= datetime.datetime.strptime(row['date],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
   )
```

That's all you have in your "type file"

Now you can read (and process) your input like this.

```
 from type_file import convert
 import csv

 with open( "date", "rb" ) as source:
     rdr= csv.DictReader( source )
     for row in rdr:
         useful_row= convert( row )
```

---

> in many cases i do not know the number of columns or the data type before runtime

This means you are doomed.

You must have an actual definition the file content or you cannot do any processing.

```
"id","value","other value"
1,23507,3
```

You don't know if "23507" should be an integer, a string, a postal code, or a floating-point (which omitted the period), a duration (in days or seconds) or some other more complex thing.  You can't hope and you can't guess.

After getting a definition, you need to write an explicit conversion function based on the actual definition.

After writing the conversion, you need to (a) test the conversion with a simple unit test, and (b) test the data to be sure it really converts.

Then you can process the file.

Comment: so from what i hear is that there is not 'smart' way of casting a string value to a specific type based on type information provided by Python. I need to create a convertion functions my self? Note that my data files are generated automatic and in many cases i do not know the number of columns or the data type before runtime!

Comment: @aweis: "there is not 'smart' way of casting a string value to a specific type"?  Python code is the *smart* way to cast a string to a specific type.  There are so many variabilities and choices and possible changes that you **must** write explicit conversion code every time.  There's no real choice.  Python code is how you write things which are "smart".  Each new file format could mean a new conversion.  Someone has to write the "type file".  No matter how "smart" you think your code can be.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the xlrd module.  If you can load your data into excel, and it knows what type is associated with each column, xlrd will give you the type when you read the excel file.  Of course, if the data is given to you as a csv then someone would have to go into the excel file and change the column types by hand.

Not sure this gets you all the way to where you want to go, but it might help