# Text to datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python time to age part 2, timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526406/python-time-to-age-part-2-timezones)

I'm using JSON files to scrape tweets and the time the tweet was posted. I want to be able to take the time (which is in plain text) and time it into a datetime object.

Here is the format that is given in the JSON file: Fri Jun 17 14:56:23 +0000 2011 ( %a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y )

I've read that the best way to do this in Python is to use strptime(). The problem is that strptime doesn't work with the %z formatter.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Cedric Julien - agreed.