# Going from twitter date to Python datetime date

Tags: python, django, date, twitter

I am receiving twitter messages that are sent at a certain date in the following format from twitter:

```
Tue Mar 29 08:11:25 +0000 2011
```

I want to store these dates in 'timestamp with time zone' field in postgresql with djangos DateTimeField field. When I store that string however I get this error:

```
ValidationError: [u'Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format.']
```

can I automatically transform the twitter datetype to a python datetime time (that does work elsewhere in my app for saving dates).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Writing something like this should convert a twitter date to a timestamp.

```
import time

ts = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))
```

**UPDATE**

For Python 3, as per 2020, you can do it in this way:

```
from datetime import datetime

# dtime = tweet['created_at']
dtime = 'Fri Oct 09 10:01:41 +0000 2015'
new_datetime = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(dtime,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print((new_datetime))
```

Comment: This gives me the following error, 'expected string or buffer'. Can you help me why?

Comment: @ZairaZafar I added an answer below which may help. I had similar errors that you had.

Answer (score 15):

Give this a go. It assumes the date format from twitter is RFC822 compliant (see the question linked to by @Adrien).

A naive datetime object is constructed (i.e. no timezone info). It is adjusted according to the timezone offset to UTC. Unless you have a need to keep the original timezone, I'd store the date time as UTC and format to local time when you display it.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from email.utils import parsedate_tz

s = 'Tue Mar 29 08:11:25 +0000 2011'

def to_datetime(datestring):
    time_tuple = parsedate_tz(datestring.strip())
    dt = datetime(*time_tuple[:6])
    return dt - timedelta(seconds=time_tuple[-1])
```

Comment: I prefer this method because it even works with timezones different from +0000 (despite the fact that Twitter always uses +0000). Django side is also better to make the resulting datetime timezone-aware using the utc timezone ( see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python) )

Answer (score 8):

A little bit old but using parse really help me with this issue

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

date = 'Fri May 10 00:44:04 +0000 2019' 
dt = parse(date)

print(dt) 
# 2019-05-10 00:44:04+00:00
```

Comment: This seems the best answer in 2019.  Any downsides to doing it this way?

Comment: Nope. This is STILL the most pythonic approach in 2021. Use a common parser.

Answer (score 3):

To get datetime with timezone you can simple use datetime.strptime as follow:

```
from datetime import datetime
s = 'Wed Jun 05 05:34:02 +0000 2019'
created_at = datetime.strptime(s, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
print(created_at)
#2019-06-05 05:34:02+00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Twitter API V2 sends date strings that look like this:

> 2020-12-15T20:17:10.000Z

This worked, to convert from string to datetime:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(THE_STRING,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

The end looks like a timezone, but it's milliseconds, hence the **%f**. The final character, "Z" is a timezone code that means UTC, as explained, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19472896/6232066).

Answer (score 2):

you can convert the date using `datetime.strptime()`, or `time.strptime()`. however, those two functions cannot parse the timezone offset (see [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6641)).

so, the only solution i see is to split the date yourself, remove the timezone offset, feed the rest to `strptime()`, and process the offset manually...

have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/526406/195823), where you will find some hints on how to parse the offset yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will print a nice date (local time) from a Twitter date (UTC).

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone    

datetime.strptime(mydata["created_at"], '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y').replace(
            tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial problem I was having was converting from the datetime that the twitter api gives to String.

The following works which addresses different comments people seem to have for above solutions which are a little unclear as to whether the starting date is already in string format or not.
This works for Python 2.7

With a tweet from the API, tweet.created_at gives the date in datetime format. At the top of your file, add `from datetime import datetime`

then use the following to get the corresponding string.

```
datetime.strftime(tweet.created_at,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y').
```

You can then use this string as described in other comments to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar strategy as SoFolichon proposed, in Python 3.x you can also use `pytz` like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pytz

datetime.strptime(tweets["created_at"], '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y').replace(
tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime(
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Hey. this gives me the following error: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not Series.

Comment: @ZairaZafar, Which version of Python do you use? In Python 3.x, it works fine for me.

Comment: im using 2.7 python

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It doesn't need any formatting strings.

```
import datetime
from email.utils import mktime_tz, parsedate_tz

def parse_datetime(value):
    time_tuple = parsedate_tz(value)
    timestamp = mktime_tz(time_tuple)

    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

print(parse_datetime('Tue Mar 29 08:11:25 +0000 2011'))
#2011-03-29 10:11:25
```

My system is at GMT +2 hence the difference included.