# django timezone: How to compare time difference in days between 2 days across DST

Tags: python, django, timezone

I'm currently working on a calendar project using django that involves some time calculation, and I encountered a problem when I try to calculate time difference between 2 datetime objects. When I create the time, I do:

```
tz = timezone.get_default_timezone()
curr_day = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime(curr_day.year,
                                                 curr_day.month,
                                                 curr_day.day,
                                                 0, 0, 0), tz)
```

When I create it, only the date matters, but since the object should be using datetime for historical reason, I added three 0's for hour, minute, second.

My program tries to compare if 2 datetime has difference of 1 in days, so I do

```
if (event1 - event2).days == 1:
    # do something
```

The problem comes up when I try to compare 03/12/2017 and 03/13/2017(03/12/2017 is the DST).

```
event1
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 13, 4, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)

event2
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 12, 5, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)

(event1-event2).days
0
```

I know that it's because the Daylight Saving Time that makes the difference less than one day, but I don't know the solution for this, because in theory the result should be 1 as well. How can I fix my code to detect this? Thanks!

Comment: What is "a day"? Is it 24 hours exactly? Related: [How can I subtract a day from a python date?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427822/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: a day might not be necessarily be 24 hrs, in my program it means 2 datetime objects identical in hour, minute, second, and the date is different by 1.

Comment: If you need identical hour, minute, second but the difference may be less/more than 24 hours then you could use the algorithm that computes `yesterday` in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427822/4279)

Comment: unrelated: you should probably use `delta // timedelta(days=1)` (or its analog on older Python versions) instead of `delta.days` if the difference may be negative.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: What is the advantage of using `delta // timedelta(days=1)`?

Comment: @unutbu: [the difference is visible if true division is used: `delta / timedelta(days=1)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508727/python-time-to-age/508742#comment39666382_508742)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the hours, minutes, days back to 0 before taking the difference:

```
In [79]: import datetime as DT
In [80]: (DT.datetime.combine(event1, DT.time(0)) - DT.datetime.combine(event2, DT.time(0))).days
Out[80]: 1
```

Note that according to this definition of "days", two timezone-aware datetimes may have a difference of 1 with respect to one timezone, and yet have difference of 0 with respect to another timezone.

Comment: I tried and it works! But I wonder what does your way to "set to 0" different from my initial object creation of "set to 0"?

Comment: note: `event1` and `event2` must be in the same timezone for the result to make sense.

Comment: I'm guessing that `event1` and `event2` have been converted to some other timezone and this is the reason why the hours is no longer zero. If that is the case, then in your code the hours was set to zero before the conversion, while in the code I posted, the hours was reset to zero after the conversion.

Comment: @da_zhuang: `event1` and `event2` from you question have different hours (`4` and `5`). The reason might be that (necessary) `tz.normalize()` is called after you "set to 0", see the discussion in [python - datetime with timezone to epoch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12166400/4279).