# Convert a timedelta to days, hours and minutes

Tags: python, timedelta

I've got a timedelta. I want the days, hours and minutes from that - either as a tuple or a dictionary... I'm not fussed.

I must have done this a dozen times in a dozen languages over the years but Python usually has a simple answer to everything so I thought I'd ask here before busting out some nauseatingly simple (yet verbose) mathematics.

Mr Fooz raises a good point.

I'm dealing with "listings" (a bit like ebay listings) where each one has a duration. I'm trying to find the time left by doing `when_added + duration - now`

Am I right in saying that wouldn't account for DST? If not, what's the simplest way to add/subtract an hour?

Comment: If it is just to get it as a *string* in HH:mm:ss format, say *"0:19:37"* from the `timedelta` object *"datetime.timedelta(seconds=1177)"*: simply [use str()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190045/how-to-convert-datetime-timedelta-to-minutes-hours-in-python/43965102#43965102)

Answer (score 521, accepted):

If you have a `datetime.timedelta` value `td`, `td.days` already gives you the "days" you want. `timedelta` values keep fraction-of-day as seconds (not directly hours or minutes) so you'll indeed have to perform "nauseatingly simple mathematics", e.g.:

```py
def days_hours_minutes(td):
    return td.days, td.seconds//3600, (td.seconds//60)%60
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if `td` is negative, `-1 // 3600` is `-1`.

Comment: why // ? instead of /

Comment: `//` is used instead of `/` to get an integer, not a float. `//` is a floor division operator: "division that results into whole number adjusted to the left in the number line", see [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators).

Comment: @EerikSvenPuudist as `jcrs` pointed out, `-1//3600` is `-1`, so why not use `int(td.seconds/3600)` instead to turn `-1` second into `0` hours rather than `1` hour backwards?

Comment: how about adding the remaining seconds as well ?
 `days, hours, minutes  = x.days, x.seconds // 3600, x.seconds %3600//60` and then 
 `seconds = x.seconds - hours*3600 - minutes*60`

Comment: WHY are these not in the standard library? `days` and `seconds` are available  but `hours` and `minutes` not? srsly? Some batteries were not included. `</rant>`

Comment: Keep in mind that you **need** to use days, one way or another, because hours going above 24 resets/wraps back to 0!

Comment: Note also that as jcrs pointed out this breaks with `-1`, and that Python's `%` doesn't work like it should for negatives... It does not work the same as C's `fmod()`, like you would expect, and like most calculators are going to do! So I recommend using Python's `math.fmod()`, with `int()` if you need to, instead of `%`... https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fmod I've concluded that for my purposes, for the most part, I'd rather just not use `timedelta` at all...

Answer (score 110):

This is a bit more compact, you get the hours, minutes and seconds in two lines.

```
days = td.days
hours, remainder = divmod(td.seconds, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
# If you want to take into account fractions of a second
seconds += td.microseconds / 1e6
```

Answer (score 38):

```py
days, hours, minutes = td.days, td.seconds // 3600, td.seconds // 60 % 60
```

As for DST, I think the best thing is to convert both `datetime` objects to seconds. This way the system calculates DST for you.

```
>>> m13 = datetime(2010, 3, 13, 8, 0, 0)  # 2010 March 13 8:00 AM
>>> m14 = datetime(2010, 3, 14, 8, 0, 0)  # DST starts on this day, in my time zone
>>> mktime(m14.timetuple()) - mktime(m13.timetuple())     # difference in seconds
82800.0
>>> _/3600                                                # convert to hours
23.0
```

Comment: `mktime()` may fail if the local timezone may have a different utc offset at different times (many do) -- you could use `pytz` module to get access to the tz database in a portable deteministic way. Also, local time may be ambiguous (50% chances of an error) -- you need some additional info to disambiguate e.g., often (not always) [dates in a log file are monotonous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26221183/4279). See [How can I subtract a day from a python date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441147/4279) that may have to deal with similar issues.

Answer (score 16):

**For all coming along and searching for an implementation:**

The above posts are related to datetime.timedelta, which is sadly not having properties for hours and seconds. So far it was not mentioned, that there is a package, which is having these. You can find it here:

- Check the source: https://github.com/andrewp-as-is/timedelta.py
- Available via pip: https://pypi.org/project/timedelta/

Example - Calculation:

```
>>> import timedelta

>>> td = timedelta.Timedelta(days=2, hours=2)

# init from datetime.timedelta
>>> td = timedelta.Timedelta(datetime1 - datetime2)
```

Example - Properties:

```
>>> td = timedelta.Timedelta(days=2, hours=2)
>>> td.total.seconds
180000
>>> td.total.minutes
3000
>>> td.total.hours
50
>>> td.total.days
2
```

I hope this could help someone...

Comment: This would also get around the limitation of timedelta, in that it depends on C. Thus, it cannot handle even moderately large times. It can only deal with day counts that are less than 1 billion, and if you use a value larger than +2G, you get a type conversion error as the underlying type appears to be just a 32-bit signed integer.

Answer (score 9):

I don't understand

```
days, hours, minutes = td.days, td.seconds // 3600, td.seconds // 60 % 60
```

how about this

```
days, hours, minutes = td.days, td.seconds // 3600, td.seconds % 3600 / 60.0
```

You get minutes and seconds of a minute as a float.

Answer (score 8):

I used the following:

```py
delta = timedelta()
totalMinute, second = divmod(delta.seconds, 60)
hour, minute = divmod(totalMinute, 60)
print(f"{hour}h{minute:02}m{second:02}s")
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a little function I put together to do this right down to microseconds:

```
def tdToDict(td:datetime.timedelta) -> dict:
    def __t(t, n):
        if t < n: return (t, 0)
        v = t//n
        return (t -  (v * n), v)
    (s, h) = __t(td.seconds, 3600)
    (s, m) = __t(s, 60)    
    (micS, milS) = __t(td.microseconds, 1000)

    return {
         'days': td.days
        ,'hours': h
        ,'minutes': m
        ,'seconds': s
        ,'milliseconds': milS
        ,'microseconds': micS
    }
```

Here is a version that returns a `tuple`:

```
# usage: (_d, _h, _m, _s, _mils, _mics) = tdTuple(td)
def tdTuple(td:datetime.timedelta) -> tuple:
    def _t(t, n):
        if t < n: return (t, 0)
        v = t//n
        return (t -  (v * n), v)
    (s, h) = _t(td.seconds, 3600)
    (s, m) = _t(s, 60)    
    (mics, mils) = _t(td.microseconds, 1000)
    return (td.days, h, m, s, mics, mils)
```

Answer (score 5):

While `pandas.Timedelta` does not provide these attributes directly, it indeed provide a method called `total_seconds`, based on which days, hours, and minutes can be easily derived:

```
import pandas as pd
td = pd.Timedelta("2 days 12:30:00")
minutes = td.total_seconds()/60
hours = minutes/60
days = hours/ 24
print(minutes, hours, days)
```

Comment: This is available even without pandas, in the standard library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds

Comment: Finally the best answer. It is most important for every other answer to mention the total_seconds() property! Otherwise you get weird numbers that are not exactly the seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way is using `str(timedelta)`. It will return a sting formatted like `3 days, 21:06:40.001000`, and you can parse hours and minutes using simple string operations or regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

While if you are using python datetime package, you can also code like below:

```
import datetime
tap_in = datetime.datetime.strptime("04:12", "%H:%M")
tap_out = datetime.datetime.strptime("18:20", "%H:%M")
num_of_hour = (tap_out - tap_in).total_seconds()/3600
num_of_hour # 14.133333333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

```
timedelta = pd.Timestamp("today") - pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01")
print(timedelta.components)
print(timedelta.components.days)
print(timedelta.components.seconds)
```

will return something like:

```
Components(days=281, hours=2, minutes=24, seconds=3, milliseconds=72, microseconds=493, nanoseconds=0) 
281
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible approach, though a bit wordier than those already mentioned. It maybe isn't the best approach for this scenario but it is handy to be able to obtain your time duration in a specific unit that isn't stored within the object (weeks, hours, minutes, milliseconds) and without having to remember or calculate conversion factors.

```py
from datetime import timedelta
one_hour = timedelta(hours=1)
one_minute = timedelta(minutes=1)
print(one_hour/one_minute)  # Yields 60.0
```

> I've got a timedelta. I want the days, hours and minutes from that - either as a tuple or a dictionary... I'm not fussed.

```py
in_time_delta = timedelta(days=2, hours=18, minutes=30)
td_d = timedelta(days=1)
td_h = timedelta(hours=1)
td_m = timedelta(minutes=1)
dmh_list = [in_time_delta.days,
            (in_time_delta%td_d)//td_h,
            (in_time_delta%td_h)//td_m]
```

Which should assign `[2, 18, 30]` to `dmh_list`

Answer (score 0):

If using *pandas* (at least version >1.0), the `Timedelta` class has a `components` attribute that returns a named tuple with all the fields nicely laid out.

e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd
delta = pd.Timestamp("today") - pd.Timestamp("2022-03-01")
print(delta.components)
```

Answer (score -5):

timedeltas have a `days` and `seconds` attribute .. you can convert them yourself with ease.