# Python subtract two dates in minutes

Tags: python

```
date1 = datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 10, 10, 15, 44)
date2 = datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 17, 8, 45, 38)
roundedA = date2.replace(second = 0, microsecond = 0)
print roundedA
roundedB = date1.replace(second = 0, microsecond = 0)
print roundedB
minutes = (roundedA - roundedB).min
print minutes
```

Result is:

```
-999999999 days, 0:00:00
```

I want to count 2 different dates differences. I subtracted above, but it does not give me what I want. How to do subtract two dates and get the result in minutes or hours.

Comment: Why not take the `days` and `hours` from your result and multiply them out accordingly?

Comment: but, I want to be exact!, it may eliminate some minutes differences

Answer (score 5):

The `timedelta.min` attribute does not represent minutes- it means the smallest possible timedelta (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.min)). If you want to get it in minutes, you can do:

```
d = roundedA - roundedB
minutes = d.days * 1440 + d.seconds / 60
```

This is because only seconds and days are stored internally in `timedelta`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also time module to get result of subtraction in seconds:

```
import time
import datetime
date1 = datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 10, 10, 15, 44)
date2 = datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 17, 8, 45, 38)
var1 = time.mktime(date1.timetuple())
var2 = time.mktime(date2.timetuple())
result_in_seconds = var2 - var1

>>> var2 - var1
599394.0
```

Or use function provided in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes)

```
>>> def days_hours_minutes(td):
...     return td.days, td.seconds//3600, (td.seconds//60)%60
... 
>>> date2 - date1
datetime.timedelta(6, 80994)
>>> days_hours_minutes(datetime.timedelta(6, 80994))
(6, 22, 29)
```