# How do I convert datetime.timedelta to minutes, hours in Python?

Tags: python, django

I get a start_date like this:

```
from django.utils.timezone import utc
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
end_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
duration = end_date - start_date
```

I get output like this:

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 5, 41038)
```

How do I convert this into normal time like the following?

10 minutes, 1 hour like this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a timedelta to days, hours and minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: The fact that there are so many people looking this up indicates that the datetime module should have this basic feature...

Answer (score 178, accepted):

There's no built-in formatter for `timedelta` objects, but it's pretty easy to do it yourself:

```
days, seconds = duration.days, duration.seconds
hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
seconds = seconds % 60
```

Or, equivalently, if you're in Python 2.7+ or 3.2+:

```
seconds = duration.total_seconds()
hours = seconds // 3600
minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
seconds = seconds % 60
```

Now you can print it however you want:

```
'{} minutes, {} hours'.format(minutes, hours)
```

For example:

```
def convert_timedelta(duration):
    days, seconds = duration.days, duration.seconds
    hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = (seconds % 60)
    return hours, minutes, seconds
td = datetime.timedelta(2, 7743, 12345)
hours, minutes, seconds = convert_timedelta(td)
print '{} minutes, {} hours'.format(minutes, hours)
```

This will print:

```
9 minutes, 50 hours
```

If you want to get "10 minutes, 1 hour" instead of "10 minutes, 1 hours", you need to do that manually too:

```
print '{} minute{}, {} hour{}'.format(minutes, 's' if minutes != 1 else '',
                                      hours, 's' if minutes != 1 else '')
```

Or you may want to write an `english_plural` function to do the `'s'` bits for you, instead of repeating yourself.

From your comments, it sounds like you actually want to keep the days separate. That's even easier:

```
def convert_timedelta(duration):
    days, seconds = duration.days, duration.seconds
    hours = seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = (seconds % 60)
    return days, hours, minutes, seconds
```

If you want to convert this to a single value to store in a database, then convert that single value back to format it, do this:

```
def dhms_to_seconds(days, hours, minutes, seconds):
    return (((days * 24) + hours) * 60 + minutes) * 60 + seconds

def seconds_to_dhms(seconds):
    days = seconds // (3600 * 24)
    hours = (seconds // 3600) % 24
    minutes = (seconds // 60) % 60
    seconds = seconds % 60
    return days, hours, minutes, seconds
```

So, putting it together:

```
def store_timedelta_in_database(thingy, duration):
    seconds = dhms_to_seconds(*convert_timedelta(duration))
    db.execute('INSERT INTO foo (thingy, duration) VALUES (?, ?)',
               thingy, seconds)
    db.commit()

def print_timedelta_from_database(thingy):
    cur = db.execute('SELECT duration FROM foo WHERE thingy = ?', thingy)
    seconds = int(cur.fetchone()[0])
    days, hours, minutes, seconds = seconds_to_dhms(seconds)
    print '{} took {} minutes, {} hours, {} days'.format(thingy, minutes, hours, days)
```

Answer (score 35):

There is no need for custom helper functions if all we need is to print the string of the form `[D day[s], ][H]H:MM:SS[.UUUUUU]`. [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object supports `str()` operation that will do this. It works even in Python 2.6.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> timedelta(seconds=90136)
datetime.timedelta(1, 3736)
>>> str(timedelta(seconds=90136))
'1 day, 1:02:16'
```

Comment: Except for the weird output format requirement of the question (which I think is not really the real requirement, just the OP having problems expressing themselves), this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 29):

A `datetime.timedelta` corresponds to the *difference* between two dates, not a date itself.  It's only expressed in terms of days, seconds, and microseconds, since larger time units like months and years don't decompose cleanly (is 30 days 1 month or 0.9677 months?).

If you want to convert a `timedelta` into hours and minutes, you can use the [`total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method to get the total number of seconds and then do some math:

```
x = datetime.timedelta(1, 5, 41038)  # Interval of 1 day and 5.41038 seconds
secs = x.total_seconds()
hours = int(secs / 3600)
minutes = int(secs / 60) % 60
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it's a good idea to caculate yourself.

If you just want a pretty output, just covert it into `str` with `str()` function or directly `print()` it.

And if there's further usage of the hours and minutes, you can parse it to `datetime` object use `datetime.strptime()`(and extract the time part with `datetime.time()` mehtod), for example:

```
import datetime

delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=10000)
time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(delta),'%H:%M:%S').time()
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) :)

Something like that:

```
my_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 7, 10, 31, 34, 243366, tzinfo=<UTC>)
print(my_date.strftime("%Y, %d %B"))
```

---

After edited your question to format `timedelta`, you could use:

```
def timedelta_tuple(timedelta_object):
   return timedelta_object.days, timedelta_object.seconds//3600, (timedelta_object.seconds//60)%60
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
# Try this code
from datetime import timedelta

class TimeDelta(timedelta):
    def __str__(self):
        _times = super(TimeDelta, self).__str__().split(':')
        if "," in _times[0]:
            _hour = int(_times[0].split(',')[-1].strip())
            if _hour:
                _times[0] += " hours" if _hour > 1 else " hour"
            else:
                _times[0] = _times[0].split(',')[0]
        else:
            _hour = int(_times[0].strip())
            if _hour:
                _times[0] += " hours" if _hour > 1 else " hour"
            else:
                _times[0] = ""
        _min = int(_times[1])
        if _min:
            _times[1] += " minutes" if _min > 1 else " minute"
        else:
            _times[1] = ""
        _sec = int(_times[2])
        if _sec:
            _times[2] += " seconds" if _sec > 1 else " second"
        else:
            _times[2] = ""
        return ", ".join([i for i in _times if i]).strip(" ,").title()
```

```
# Test
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=10))
'10 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=60))
'01 Minute'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=90))
'01 Minute, 30 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3000))
'50 Minutes'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600))
'1 Hour'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3690))
'1 Hour, 01 Minute, 30 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3660))
'1 Hour, 01 Minute'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3630))
'1 Hour, 30 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*20))
'20 Hours'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*20 + 3000))
'20 Hours, 50 Minutes'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*20 + 3630))
'21 Hours, 30 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*20 + 3660))
'21 Hours, 01 Minute'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*20 + 3690))
'21 Hours, 01 Minute, 30 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24))
'1 Day'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24 + 10))
'1 Day, 10 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24 + 60))
'1 Day, 01 Minute'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24 + 90))
'1 Day, 01 Minute, 30 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24 + 3000))
'1 Day, 50 Minutes'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24 + 3600))
'1 Day, 1 Hour'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24 + 3630))
'1 Day, 1 Hour, 30 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24 + 3660))
'1 Day, 1 Hour, 01 Minute'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24 + 3690))
'1 Day, 1 Hour, 01 Minute, 30 Seconds'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24*2))
'2 Days'
>>> str(TimeDelta(seconds=3600*24*2 + 9999))
'2 Days, 2 Hours, 46 Minutes, 39 Seconds'
```

Answer (score 4):

I defined own helper function to convert timedelta object to 'HH:MM:SS' format - only hours, minutes and seconds, without changing hours to days.

```
def format_timedelta(td):
    hours, remainder = divmod(td.total_seconds(), 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    hours, minutes, seconds = int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)
    if hours < 10:
        hours = '0%s' % int(hours)
    if minutes < 10:
        minutes = '0%s' % minutes
    if seconds < 10:
        seconds = '0%s' % seconds
    return '%s:%s:%s' % (hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative for this (older) question is to create a *relative time* from a timedelta converted to seconds. This can be accomplished using the `time.gmtime(...)` method that accepts seconds since [the epoch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26205/109137):

```
>>> time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.gmtime(36901))  # secs = 36901
'10:15:01'
```

And, that's it! (NOTE: Here's a [link to format specifiers for `time.strftime()`](http://strftime.org/) so the difference can be truncated to any units, as needed. ...)

Notably, this technique is also a great way to tell if your current time zone is actually in daylight savings time or not. (It provides an offset of 0 or 1 hours meaning it can be interpreted basically as a boolean.)

```
import datetime
import pytz
import time

pacific=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
now=datetime.datetime.now()
# pacific.dst(now).total_seconds() yields 3600 secs. [aka 1 hour]
time.strftime("%-H", time.gmtime(pacific.dst(now).total_seconds()))
'1'
```

This can be rendered to a method `is_standard_time(...)` where `1` means true and `0` means false.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to print the date in that format? This is the Python documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 7, 10, 31, 34, 243366)
>>> print a.strftime('%Y %d %B, %M:%S%p')
>>> 2013 07 January, 31:34AM
```

For the timedelta:

```
>>> a =  datetime.timedelta(0,5,41038)
>>> print '%s seconds, %s microseconds' % (a.seconds, a.microseconds)
```

But please notice, you should make sure it has the related value. For the above cases, it doesn't have the hours and minute values, and you should calculate from the seconds.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert. Looks he updated his questions. I also updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=10)
#python 2.7
```