# How to get total hours and minutes for timedelta in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I return or turn a timedelta, which is bigger than 24 hours, into an object containing the total hours and minutes (for example, 26:30) instead of "1 day, 2:30"?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use `total_seconds()` to compute the number of seconds. This can then be turned into minutes or hours:

```
>>> datetime.timedelta(days=3).total_seconds()
259200.0
```

Comment: Right answer, but it would be helpful to add the simple `//60` and `%60` uses needed to turn it into an (hours, days) pair!

Comment: Thanks. I ended using the answer I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190045/how-to-convert-datetime-timedelta-to-minutes-hours-in-python

Answer (score 31):

Completing the answer of Visser using [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) :

```
import datetime
duration = datetime.timedelta(days = 2, hours = 4, minutes = 15)
```

Once we got a `timedelta` object:

```
totsec = duration.total_seconds()
h = totsec//3600
m = (totsec%3600)//60
sec =(totsec%3600)%60 # just for reference
print("%d:%d" %(h,m))

Out: 52:15
```

Answer (score 2):

```
offset_seconds = timedelta.total_seconds()

if offset_seconds < 0:
    sign = "-"
else:
    sign = "+"

# we will prepend the sign while formatting
if offset_seconds < 0:
    offset_seconds *= -1

offset_hours = offset_seconds / 3600.0
offset_minutes = (offset_hours % 1) * 60

offset = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(int(offset_hours), int(offset_minutes))
offset = sign + offset
```