# timedelta64 presented with 0 days when smaller then 1 day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe with at least 2 datetime columns

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

dfstr = StringIO(u"""
eqpt;starttm;endtm;use_count;desc
AT1;2017-04-01 10:35;2017-04-01 11:05;2;test asdf1
AT2;2017-04-01 11:00;2017-04-01 11:30;5;test asdf2
AT1;2017-04-01 11:00;2017-04-01 11:30;4;test asdf3
AT3;2017-04-01 10:45;2017-04-01 11:45;3;test asdf4
CBL1;2017-04-01 11:10;2017-04-1 11:40;4;test asdf5
""")
df = pd.read_csv(dfstr, sep=";", parse_dates=["starttm", "endtm"])
```

I would like to compute the duration of the interruptions between consecutive
`starttm` and  `endtm`
I can take the simple difference

```
r=(df['starttm']-df['endtm'].shift(-1))
```

But then my result look like

```
0   -1 days +23:30:00
1   -1 days +23:30:00
2   -1 days +23:30:00
3   -1 days +23:00:00
4   -1 days +23:30:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

which is correct numerically. However, I would need it to be in a more human readable format as `0 days -30:00:00`
How to round to 0 days?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912803/how-to-get-total-hours-and-minutes-for-timedelta-in-python?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190045/how-to-convert-datetime-timedelta-to-minutes-hours-in-python)