# datetime format over 24 hours

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to add time and have the output as `hh:mm:ss`, but when datetime gets over 24 hours it becomes `x Days, hh:mm:ss`. Is there anyway to only have `hh:mm:ss` greater than 24 hours?

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

# intro
print("Welcome to TimeCalc")

print("Calculating Durations")

clear = True
while clear == True:
    # first input
    firstNumber = True
    while firstNumber == True:
        time_1 = input("Please enter a time [hh:mm:ss] including 0s: ")
        if len(time_1) > 0 and len(time_1) >= 8 and time_1[-6] == ":" and time_1[-3] == ":" and int(time_1[-5:-3]) < 60 and int(time_1[-2:]) < 60:
            hours_1 = time_1[:-6]
            minutes_1 = time_1[-5:-3]
            seconds_1 = time_1[-2:]
            hours_1 = int(hours_1)
            minutes_1 = int(minutes_1)
            seconds_1 = int(seconds_1)
            firstNumber = False
        else:
            print("Invalid Syntax")
    time_1 = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours_1, minutes=minutes_1, seconds=seconds_1)

    cont = True
    while cont == True:
        # second input
        secondNumber = True
        while secondNumber == True:
            time_2 = input("Please enter a time to add [hh:mm:ss] including 0s: ")
            if len(time_2) > 0 and len(time_2) >= 8 and time_2[-6] == ":" and time_2[-3] == ":" and int(time_2[-5:-3]) < 60 and int(time_2[-2:]) < 60:
                hours_2 = time_2[:-6]
                minutes_2 = time_2[-5:-3]
                seconds_2 = time_2[-2:]
                hours_2 = int(hours_2)
                minutes_2 = int(minutes_2)
                seconds_2 = int(seconds_2)
                secondNumber = False
            else:
                print("Invalid Syntax")
        time_2 = datetime.timedelta(hours = hours_2, minutes = minutes_2, seconds = seconds_2)

        total = time_1 + time_2
        print("The total duration is: " + str(total))

        # continue, clear, or exit
        choice = input("Continue: Y | Clear: N | Exit: X: ")
        if choice == "Y" or choice == "y":
            time_1 = total
        elif choice == "N" or choice == "n":
            cont = False
        elif choice == "X" or choice == "x":
            quit()
```

Comment: Since I can reproduce your program, you get an upvote.

Comment: Related: [how to get total hours and minutes for timedelta in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912803/how-to-get-total-hours-and-minutes-for-timedelta-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

after **total** variable, can you try to put this code, maybe this is not a super solution but it works

```
seconds = int(total.total_seconds())
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)

print("The total duration is: {h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:02d}".format(h=hours,                                                                 
                                                        m=minutes, s=seconds))
```

Comment: @Mulliganaceous if he want this, he will do it :) i only give a solution

Comment: @Mulliganaceous i add this :)

Comment: hmm.. i'm searching now for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.strftime()` method to format your datetime string.

For example,

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.delta(hours=1)
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2017,10,30,23,10,10) + d
>>> dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
'00:10:10'
```

Hope it help.

Comment: `total` is a timedelta without a `strftime` method.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous if so you can just adding a `datetime.datetime(0,0,0,0,0,0)` to that `timedelta` object. what I provided is just a hint. 

Beautiful is better than ugly.