# How to get just the hours and minutes from a datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a program that keeps track of when a person signs on, and when they sign off over discord. The program is given the signing on time, and signing off time in the form of a datetime object, and it subtracts them from each other, giving me the total. The problem is I want it to only give me the hours and minutes, not seconds and milliseconds. 
**Code shown below:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "on" in message.content:
        player = message.author
        time = message.timestamp
        message_type = 'on'
        with open(str(player) + " on", 'w') as f:
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate()
            f.write(str(time))
    elif "off" in message.content:
        player = message.author
        off_time = message.timestamp
        with open(str(player) + " on",'r+') as f:
            on_time = f.readline()
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate()
        on_time = parser.parse(on_time)
        total = off_time - on_time
        print(total)
```

**Note:** The total object is a timedelta object, not a timedate object.

Comment: Unfortunately, while the first dup has exactly the answer you want, it's not the accepted answer there., so you have to go to [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45608647/908494).

Answer (score 2):

the `.minute` \ `.hour` properties gives you the information as an `int`

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().minute
datetime.datetime.now().hour
```

if you want to get a new datetime object use the `replace` method:

```
datetime.datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```

---

for a `timedelta` object use the `.total_seconds()` method

```
timedelta_obj = datetime.datetime(2018,1,2) - datetime.datetime(2018,1,1)
seconds = timedelta_obj.total_seconds()
rounded_minute = round(seconds/60)
```

Comment: But how do I use this in my code? I want to use the object I made already

Comment: It's a timedelta object, not a datetime object

Comment: the edit with the note was not there when i made the original answer. added the answer for `timedelta`.

Comment: Isn't that taking the time from then? I want it to take it from the timedelta called total