# Comparing a user's last seen time to now()

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, momentjs

Hi I am trying to compare the last seen time of a user to now using flask-moment. Here is the logic:

```
user.last_seen = 3 mins ago #I already know how to get this using flask-moment

time_now = 5:00 pm
```

My goal is to do this:

```
{% if (time_now - user.last_seen) <= 5 mins %}
...do something...
{% else %}
...do other thing ....
{% endif %}
```

Both times are variable.
I am able to get the two times but I don't know how to compare them like I did above.
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can do calculations either in Moment or in Python (both support this) but I think the module may be confusing you. If `time_now` and `user.last_seen` are both `datetime` objects in Python then your code above will work and you'll get a `timedelta` object.

Comment: @Cfreak can you please show me how you would do it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Cfreak suggested, if `time_now` and `user.last_seen` are both `datetime` objects in Python, you can calculate the `timedelta` between these two `datetime`, then cal the function `total_seconds` and convert the `timedelta` to `minutes`, so that you can compare to 5 mins. like this:

```
import datetime
last_seen= datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 2, 11, 15, 17, 748000)
time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_delta_seconds = (time_now -last_seen).total_seconds() #get timedelta and calculate total seconds
time_delta_minutes = time_delta_seconds/60 # convert to minutes 4.808866666666666
```

Then you can compare if `time_delta_minutes` is less than 5 mins or not

Comment: Thanks @Tiny.D Just what I need!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate another datetime object based on the last seen value you get and do the following. This is just the an example. You can do the conversion from hours to minutes, seconds  and you can do timedelta(minutes=1) or timedelta(microseconds=1)  too

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    time_now=datetime.now()
    last_seen_time=datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=3)
    print(time_now-last_seen_time)
```

you can use this to convert the result which is a timedelta object to minutes, seconds etc [How to convert datetime.timedelta to minutes, hours in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190045/how-to-convert-datetime-timedelta-to-minutes-hours-in-python)