# How to calculate time difference in minutes from 2 data frame columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 2 Panda data frame columns in datetime format and want to get the time difference in minutes. with my code, I  get output (output type is "timedelta64[ns]") with days and hours, etc. How can I get it in minutes? Thank you

```
df['TIME_TO_REPORT']= df['TEST_TIME'] - df['RECEIPT_DATE_TIME']
```

Output

```
    0        0 days 05:58:00
    1        0 days 03:46:00
    2        0 days 05:25:00
    3        0 days 05:24:00
    4        0 days 05:24:00
```

Comment: I think there is not implemented to do this directly. You will need to calculate it based on your delta. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190143/12340367

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `total_seconds` to get the time duration in seconds, and then divide by 60 to convert it to minutes

```
df['TIME_TO_REPORT']= (df['TEST_TIME'] - df['RECEIPT_DATE_TIME']).dt.total_seconds() / 60
```

Comment: Yes it's works. Thank you very much