# How do i reach to hours in datetime

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
random_date = datetime(2022, 6, 19, 12, 37, 54)
time = today - random_date

print(time.hours)
```

How do I find how many hours have passed since random_date in this code?

Comment: Does the code you provided not do what you describe?

Comment: Your `time` value is a `timedelta`. Check out the docs for this class to get details about how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you may want to do this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
random_date = datetime(2022, 6, 19, 12, 37, 54)
time = today - random_date

# Use x2 slashes '//' in the division in order to get 
# an exact value 
print(time.total_seconds() / 3600)
```

*Source: [How do I convert datetime.timedelta to minutes, hours in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190045/how-do-i-convert-datetime-timedelta-to-minutes-hours-in-python/43965102)*

*Datetime docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html*

**Note:** You can also use x2 slashes '//' in the division in order to round the number to floor.

Comment: For future reference, feel free to edit your original answer and undeleting it instead of posting a new answer. You may also want to include a version that uses `/` and explain the difference between `/` and `//`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice didn't know I can undelete answers. tysm ❤️