# Django timezone.make_aware raised AmbiguousTimeError for 2014-10-26 1:45:00

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz

I found some strange things. Here some examples.

```
from django.utils import timezone
value = u'2014-10-26 01:45:00'
#I know that a variable has  'Europe / Moscow' timezone. Let's tell Django about it.
TZ = timezone.pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
d = timezone.datetime.strptime(value,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print timezone.make_aware(d,TZ)
#raised AmbiguousTimeError: 2014-10-26 01:45:00
```

And then the fun begins

```
print timezone.make_aware(d+timezone.timedelta(minutes=15),TZ)
#out: 2014-10-26 02:00:00+03:00
print timezone.make_aware(d+timezone.timedelta(minutes=14),TZ)
#raised AmbiguousTimeError
print timezone.make_aware(d-timezone.timedelta(minutes=46),TZ)
#out: 2014-10-26 00:59:00+04:00
print timezone.make_aware(d-timezone.timedelta(minutes=45),TZ)
#raised AmbiguousTimeError
```

So AmbiguousTimeError raised between 2014-10-26 00:59:00 and 2014-10-26 02:00:00

WHY? And how solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timezon.make_aware(d, TZ)` is equivalent to `TZ.localize(d, is_dst=None)` that raises an error for ambiguous times: `2014-10-26 01:45:00` happens twice in Europe/Moscow timezone:

```
# Europe/Moscow               UTC                           timestamp
2014-10-26 00:45:00 MSK+0400; 2014-10-25 20:45:00 UTC+0000; 1414269900
2014-10-26 01:00:00 MSK+0400; 2014-10-25 21:00:00 UTC+0000; 1414270800
2014-10-26 01:15:00 MSK+0400; 2014-10-25 21:15:00 UTC+0000; 1414271700
2014-10-26 01:30:00 MSK+0400; 2014-10-25 21:30:00 UTC+0000; 1414272600
2014-10-26 01:45:00 MSK+0400; 2014-10-25 21:45:00 UTC+0000; 1414273500
2014-10-26 01:15:00 MSK+0300; 2014-10-25 22:15:00 UTC+0000; 1414275300
2014-10-26 01:30:00 MSK+0300; 2014-10-25 22:30:00 UTC+0000; 1414276200
2014-10-26 01:45:00 MSK+0300; 2014-10-25 22:45:00 UTC+0000; 1414277100
2014-10-26 02:00:00 MSK+0300; 2014-10-25 23:00:00 UTC+0000; 1414278000
```

Notice: the utc offset is changed from `+0400` to `+0300` at 2am ([Федеральный закон от 21 июля 2014 г. N 248-ФЗ](http://graph.document.kremlin.ru/page.aspx?1;3644925)).

To avoid the exception, you could call `TZ.localize(d)` (note: no `is_dst=None`) that works fine for existing non-ambiguous times but may fail (return wrong answer) for non-existing or ambiguous times.

If [pytz Bug #1378150: Enhance support for end-of-DST-like ambiguous time](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1378150) is fixed then you could use `TZ.localize(d, is_dst=True)`, `TZ.localize(d, is_dst=False)`  to get time before and after the transition correspondingly.

If the bug is not fixed you could use my answer from [Parsing of Ordered Timestamps in Local Time (to UTC) While Observing Daylight Saving Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221183/4279) to get the time *after* the transition:

```py
# `naive` is a naive datetime object in local (Europe/Moscow) time
if tz.localize(naive, is_dst=False) == tz.localize(naive, is_dst=True):
    # Example: 2014/10/26 in Europe/Moscow timezone
    # ambiguous time but is_dst=False/True yield the same result
    # i.e., tz.localize() can't help, find UTC time  manually
    #NOTE: assume there is no other changes to UTC offset today (local.day)
    new_offset = tz.localize(naive + timedelta(1), is_dst=None).utcoffset()
    assert tz.localize(naive).utcoffset() != new_offset
    utc = (naive - new_offset).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    local = utc.astimezone(tz)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of Daylight Savings Time.

At 2:00am on October 26, Muscovites will set their clocks back an hour. That means that they will see, for example, 1:30am twice on that day. So times between 1:00am and 2:00am are ambiguous, and Python / pytz is telling you that.

How you deal with that is going to be application-specific. You need to decide which 1:30am you're talking about (i.e. which UTC time you're talking about).

(Apparently this is the last year that most Russians will deal with DST. See [this article](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-abandons-permanent-summer-time.html) for some interesting background.)

Comment: it is not DST. Europe/Moscow has UTC+0400 offset all year round. That offset is changed (by a specific government order) to UTC+0300 at 26 October 2014. Though the effect is the same as end-of-DST transition ("fall back") e.g., see [Bug #1378150 "Enhance support for end-of-DST-like ambiguous time..." `pytz` bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1378150) -- it means that even explicit `TZ.localize(naive, is_dst=True)` (or `is_dst=False`) won't give the desired time until the bug is fixed.