# Quickly parse Python datetime in a non-local timezone, adjusting for daylight savings

Tags: python, performance, datetime, optimization, numpy

I need to quickly turn an ISO 8601 datetime string--with no timezone in the string, but known to be in the US/Pacific timezone--into a numpy `datetime64` object.

If my machine were in US/Pacific time, I could simply run `numpy.datetime64(s)`. However, this assumes that strings without timezones are in the local timezone. Furthermore, I can't easily specify the US/Pacific timezone in ISO 8601 format, because it is sometimes `-0800` and sometimes `-0700` depending on daylight savings time.

So far, the fastest solution I have is `numpy.datetime64(pandas.Timestamp(s).tz_localize(tz='US/Pacific', ambiguous=True))`. This takes 70µs on my machine. It would be good if I could get this at least an order of magnitude faster (`numpy.datetime64(s)` in local time takes 4 µs but is incorrect as described above). Is this possible?

Comment: If performance is a concern, you must be doing this millions of times, right? Is the offset the same each time? If so, perhaps just use `numpy.datetime64(s)` on all of them, and then use numpy arithmetic to shift all of them by the same offset amount in one fell blow.

Comment: @unutbu: Unfortunately, the offset is not necessarily the same: some of the datetimes are during DST periods and some of them are not. Also, it seems like even calculating the DST adjustment per-datetime myself would be error-prone?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't found a faster way. But in any case, beware that `np.datetime64(pd.Timestamp(s, tz='US/Pacific'))` may not be giving you the desired result. Consider the ISO 8601 datetime string `'2000-04-02T03:00:00-07:00'`. Without the timezone you'd have `s = '2000-04-02T03:00:00'`. But `np.datetime64(pd.Timestamp(s, tz='US/Pacific'))` returns `numpy.datetime64('2000-04-02T04:00:00.000000-0700')`, so this is not round-tripping properly.

Comment: what is your OS? Python version? `numpy` version? `pandas` version? Can you upgrade?

Comment: @unutbu: Good catch on the incorrectness! The right call is `np.datetime64(pd.Timestamp(s).tz_localize(tz=tz, ambiguous=True))`, which agrees with the faster method in your answer but is almost 2x slower than the original (so 200x slower than your result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that without the offset some localtimes and therefore their datetime
strings are ambiguous. For example, the ISO 8601 datetime strings

```
2000-10-29T01:00:00-07:00
2000-10-29T01:00:00-08:00
```

both map to the same string `2000-10-29T01:00:00` when the offset is removed.

So it may not always be possible to reconstitute a unique timezone-aware
datetime from a datetime string without offset.

However, we could make a choice in these ambigous
situations and accept that not all ambiguous dates will be correctly converted.

---

If you are using Unix, you can use [time.tzset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.tzset) to change the process's local timezone:

```
import os
import time
os.environ['TZ'] = tz
time.tzset()
```

You could then convert the datetime strings to NumPy datetime64's using

```
def using_tzset(date_strings, tz):
    os.environ['TZ'] = tz
    time.tzset()
    return np.array(date_strings, dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

---

Note however that `using_tzset` does not always produce the same value as the method you proposed:

```
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tz = 'US/Pacific'
N = 10**5
dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='H', tz=tz)
date_strings_tz = dates.format(formatter=lambda x: x.isoformat())
date_strings = [d.rsplit('-', 1)[0] for d in date_strings_tz]

def orig(date_strings, tz):
    return [np.datetime64(pd.Timestamp(s, tz=tz)) for s in date_strings]

def using_tzset(date_strings, tz):
    os.environ['TZ'] = tz
    time.tzset()
    return np.array(date_strings, dtype='datetime64[ns]')

npdates = dates.asi8.view('datetime64[ns]')
x = np.array(orig(date_strings, tz))
y = using_tzset(date_strings, tz)
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': npdates, 'str': date_strings_tz, 'orig': x, 'using_tzset': y})
```

This indicates that the original method, `orig`, fails to recover the original date 172 times:

```
print((df['dates'] != df['orig']).sum())
172
```

while `using_tzset` fails 11 times:

```
print((df['dates'] != df['using_tzset']).sum())
11
```

Note however, that the 11 times that `using_tzset` fails are due to the ambiguity in local datetimes due to DST.

This shows some of the discrepancies:

```
mask = df['dates'] != df['using_tzset']
idx = np.where(mask.shift(1) | mask)[0]
print(df[['dates', 'str', 'using_tzset']].iloc[idx]).head(6)

#                     dates                        str         using_tzset
# 7248  2000-10-29 08:00:00  2000-10-29T01:00:00-07:00 2000-10-29 08:00:00
# 7249  2000-10-29 09:00:00  2000-10-29T01:00:00-08:00 2000-10-29 08:00:00
# 15984 2001-10-28 08:00:00  2001-10-28T01:00:00-07:00 2001-10-28 08:00:00
# 15985 2001-10-28 09:00:00  2001-10-28T01:00:00-08:00 2001-10-28 08:00:00
# 24720 2002-10-27 08:00:00  2002-10-27T01:00:00-07:00 2002-10-27 08:00:00
# 24721 2002-10-27 09:00:00  2002-10-27T01:00:00-08:00 2002-10-27 08:00:00
```

As you can see the discrepancies occur when the date strings in the `str` column 
become ambiguous when the offset is removed.

So `using_tzset` appears to produce the correct result up to ambiguous datetimes.

---

Here is a timeit benchmark comparing `orig` and `using_tzset`:

```
In [95]: %timeit orig(date_strings, tz)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.43 s per loop

In [96]: %timeit using_tzset(date_strings, tz)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.7 ms per loop
```

So `using_tzset` is over 100x faster than `orig` when N = 10**5.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realize it was possible to set the timezone and have Numpy pick it up. You said "the machine's local timezone", but this is actually the *process's* timezone, right? It won't interfere with other stuff on the machine?

Comment: Yes; thanks for the correction. `tzset` changes the process's notion of local timezone.

Comment: Awesome. Sounds like this is the way we'll go until there's a way to give numpy a locale to parse in.

Comment: @BenKuhn: if the timestamps are ordered then `pytz` allows to [handle ambiguous times too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26221183/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Did you time your script? I tried to adapt it, but unfortunately, it was basically the same as the Pandas method I outlined above.

Comment: @BenKuhn: the point of the example is to get the correct result. You can use it to test your faster methods.