# Calculating epoch time where difference of seconds is zero, getting 5:30 hrs more time

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, epoch

The time_orign_epoch,should be 1970-01-01 00:00:00,why i am getting 5:30 more?

```
time_origin_epoch = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
print time_origin_epoch
1970-01-01 05:30:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you live in India!

How did I know that?

Well, a timestamp of 0 means 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  Since your output shows 05:30:00, your time zone is UTC+05:30.  And India is one of the few places in the world with a timezone offset which is not a whole number of hours.

When you construct a datetime in Python using `fromtimestamp()`, the default is to use your local timezone for the conversion.  This corresponds to calling the classic C function `localtime()` rather than `gmtime()`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You're right, thanks for pointing out my mistake.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @ J.F.Sebastian and @ John Zwinck Thank u !!

Answer (score 0):

Running your code gives me a result that is five hours behind what it should be. This is consistent with the fact that I am in EST and am five hours behind UTC. 
If you are simply looking to confirm correct output, then check your time zone, I would guess you are somewhere in Eastern Asia. However, if you need a zeroes value produced by the program itself, try resetting your timezone to UTC from the program, and running that snippet again.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269260/quickly-parse-python-datetime-in-a-non-local-timezone-adjusting-for-daylight-sa) answer:

If you are using Unix, you can use time.tzset to change the process's local timezone:

```
import os
import time
os.environ['TZ'] = tz
time.tzset()
```

You could then convert the datetime strings to NumPy datetime64's using

```
def using_tzset(date_strings, tz):
    os.environ['TZ'] = tz
    time.tzset()
    return np.array(date_strings, dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```