# Compare times with python

Tags: python, datetime

I have data in a file with dates marked, for example, '2015.05.05-11:46', and want to read these lines and then see if they fulfill certain conditions. For example, as input to the function, I may have

```
get_times('hour', -3.0, -1.2)
```

which has function defintion:

```
get_times(unit, start_time, end_time):
```

which means I want to return all strings that are from -3.0 hours in the past to -1.2 hours in the past. I can get the current time with `now = datetime.datetime.now()`. Assuming I read in `time1 = '2015.05.05-11:46'`, how do I compare that to `now` and find out if it is within `start_time` and `end_time` `unit`s from now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare time from the file, you should convert it to UTC time (POSIX timestamp) or an aware datetime object (local time + utc offset).

```
start_time, end_time = get_times('hour', -3, -1.2)
if start_time <= utc_time < end_time:
   # utc_time is in between
```

You should **not** use `start_time <= naive_local_time < end_time`. [Convert input time to UTC or create an aware datetime objects instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79797/4279).

If local times in your input file are consecutive then you could use that fact to disambiguate the timestamps if necessary, see [Parsing of Ordered Timestamps in Local Time (to UTC) While Observing Daylight Saving Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221183/4279).

More explanation and solutions that use `time.mktime()`, `pytz`, aware datetime objects are in: [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279).

#### Why you should not use `datetime.now()`

`datetime.now()` returns local time as a naive datetime object may be ambiguous e.g., during a DST transition:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
>>> tz.localize(datetime(2015,11,1,1,30), is_dst=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 349, in localize
    raise AmbiguousTimeError(dt)
pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: 2015-11-01 01:30:00
>>> tz.localize(datetime(2015,11,1,1,30), is_dst=True).astimezone(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 1, 5, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> tz.localize(datetime(2015,11,1,1,30), is_dst=False).astimezone(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 1, 6, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Note: if you remove UTC offset then the same local time may correspond to  different UTC time. `datetime.utcnow()` is unambiguous (except perhaps *during* a leap second such as `2015-06-30T23:59:60Z`).

#### How to implement `get_times('hour', -3.0, -1.2)`

Use UTC time or aware datetime objects:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_times(unit, relative_start, relative_end):
    relative_start, relative_end = [timedelta(**{unit+'s': v})
                                    for v in [relative_start, relative_end]]
    now = datetime.utcnow() # or datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()
    return now + relative_start, now + relative_end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<` and `>` operators normally.
But for that to work, you have to make all data be `datetime` type.

For instance:

```
time_str = "2015.05.05-11:46"
reference_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, "%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M")

start_time = reference_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
end_time = reference_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=1.2)
now = datetime.datetime.now()

if end_time <= now <= start_time:
    print 'It is in between'
```

---

You can also pass arguments to `timedelta` function using a dictionary:

```
>>> a = datetime.timedelta(hours=3, minutes=10)
>>> args = {'hours': 3, 'minutes': 10}
>>> b = datetime.timedelta(**args)
>>> a == b
True
```

Comment: Nice. I can put in test cases for finding `unit`, but is there a way to represent `hours` as a string or does it have to be hardcoded as `hours`?

Comment: Where? in `timedelta` argument? That is a keyword, it has to be written as so

Comment: @Laurbert515 `datetime.timedelta(**{unit: start_time})` - although you'll need to ensure that the value of `unit` matches the expected argument name, so `"hours"` rather than `"hour"`

Answer (score 1):

Use datetime.strptime to convert your string '2015.05.05-11:46'

```
then = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015.05.05-11:46', "%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M")

now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Then use datetime.timedelta to compare times.

```
tdelta = now - then

if datetime.timedelta(hours=1.2) < tdelta < datetime.timedelta(hours=3.0):
    print "In range"
```

For writing your function, you'll probably want to stick to the units that are in datetime.timedelta, unless you have a good reason not to.

```
class datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])
```

So, `'days', 'seconds', 'microseconds', 'milliseconds', 'minutes', 'hours', 'weeks'`

Comment: And then use datetime.timedelta to figure out the start time and end times in datetime format so you can compare them.  http://pymotw.com/2/datetime/

Answer (score 1):

hope this is what you are looking for:

```py
import datetime
import time


def get_times(unit, start_time, end_time):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()
    matched_dates = []
    for date in your_file:
        converted_date = time.strptime(date,"%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M")
        if converted_date.tm_hour > (now.tm_hour + start_time) and converted_date.tm_hour < (now.tm_hour + end_time):
            matched_dates.append(date)
    return matched_dates
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things need to be done in your situation. First, you need to convert your datetime strings to datetime objects for easy comparison. We do this via [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
input_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M')
```

We also need the function to return start and end times based on your input. If you can make a slight modification and utilize `hours` instead of `hour`, we can do this without setting up a large `if/elif` block.

```
def get_times(unit, start_time, end_time):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_kwarg = {unit: start_time}
    end_kwarg = {unit: end_time}
    time_start = now + datetime.timedelta(**start_kwarg)
    time_end = now + datetime.timedelta(**end_kwarg)
    return time_start, time_end
```

This takes your `unit` and creates a dictionary that is passed as a keyword argument to [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). Since `hours` is one of the arguments it accepts, we can utilize the keyword instead of mapping `hour` to `hours`. Then we return start and end time.

Finally, we just need to compare that the input time is between start and end:

```
start < input_datetime < end
```

A final script could look like this:

```
import datetime

def get_times(unit, start_time, end_time):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_kwarg = {unit: start_time}
    end_kwarg = {unit: end_time}
    time_start = now + datetime.timedelta(**start_kwarg)
    time_end = now + datetime.timedelta(**end_kwarg)
    return time_start, time_end

start, end = get_times('hours', -3.0, -1.2)

input_times = [
    '2015.05.12-11:46',
    '2014.05.12-11:46',
    '2016.05.12-11:46',
    '2015.04.12-11:46',
    '2015.05.05-11:46'
    ]

for i in input_times:
    input_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M')
    print "{} => {}".format(input_datetime, start < input_datetime < end)
```

Output would look like this (if run at 12:46pm on 2015-05-12):

```
2015-05-12 11:46:00 => True
2014-05-12 11:46:00 => False
2016-05-12 11:46:00 => False
2015-04-12 11:46:00 => False
2015-05-05 11:46:00 => False
```

Comment: local time may be ambiguous. Don't compare naive datetime objects that represent local time directly. [Use UTC time instead or aware datetime objects instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30207195/4279)