# How do I convert timedelta to time in Python?

Tags: python, time, timedelta

I did so:

```
str_7 = str(waiting_time - timedelta(microseconds=waiting_time.microseconds)).split(":")
col_7 = time(int(str_7[0]), int(str_7[1]), int(str_7[2]))
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: waiting_time is a datetime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. `timedelta` is logically a difference between two points in time and time is usually a single point in time. Sounds like you're trying to convert apples to oranges. Can we get some more context about your problem?

Comment: Also, your variable names seem to suggest you're doing multiple similar things one after another. It might be better to use a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `waiting_time` is a datetime, then `waiting_time - timedelta()` is **also** a `datetime`. You can just use `.time()` on that object to get the `datetime.time()` object from that:

```
new_dt = waiting_time - timedelta(microseconds=waiting_time.microseconds)
col_7 = new_dt.time()
```

However, if all you are doing is remove the `waiting_time.microseconds` component, then do so with the [`datetime.datetime.replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
col_7 = waiting_time.replace(microsecond=0).time()
```

or, if you need to produce a string for *just* the time, then use [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to produce a string that simply ignores the microseconds component:

```
col_7 = waiting_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # hours:minutes:seconds
```

Comment: `waiting_time - timedelta()` is a timedelta, not a datetime.
if datetime - timedelta, the result is timedelta.

Comment: @CíceroAlves: no, `datetime - datetime` gives you a timedelta. `datetime - timedelta()` gives you a new `datetime`. Are you saying `waiting_time` is a timedelta instead? `timedelta - timedelta` gives you a `timedelta` too.

Comment: new_dt = waiting_time - timedelta(microseconds=waiting_time.microseconds) is a timedelta, you can't add to it .time()

Comment: @A.khou: that’s the same conversation I had with Cicero. **It depends on the type of `waiting_time`** what is returned when you subtract a `timedelta` instance.