# How to convert a timedelta to a string and back again

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

Dateutil's `timedelta` object appears to have a custom `__str__` method:

```
In [1]: from datetime import timedelta

In [2]: td = timedelta(hours=2)

In [3]: str(td)
Out[3]: '2:00:00'
```

What I'd like to do is re-create a `timedelta` object from its string representation. As far as I can tell, however, the `datetime.parser.parse` method will always return a `datetime.datetime` object (cf. https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html):

```
In [4]: import dateutil.parser

In [5]: dateutil.parser.parse(str(td))
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 25, 2, 0)
```

The only way I see now to do this is to, in the parlance of [Convert a timedelta to days, hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes), 'bust out some nauseatingly simple (but verbose) mathematics' to obtain the seconds, minutes, hours, etc., and pass these back to the `__init__` of a new `timedelta`. Or is there perhaps a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module [pytimeparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytimeparse/1.1.5), which was inspired by [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string), seems to do the heavy lifting by returning the number of seconds. I just put a wrapper around it which returns a `timedelta` object with the same number of seconds:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import datetime
import pytimeparse
import unittest

def reconstruct_timedelta(td_string):
    seconds = pytimeparse.parse(td_string)
    return datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)

class TestReconstruction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_reconstruct_timedelta_is_inverse_of_str(self):
        td = datetime.timedelta(weeks=300, days=20, hours=3, minutes=4, milliseconds=254, microseconds=984)
        td_reconstructed = reconstruct_timedelta(str(td))
        self.assertTrue(td == td_reconstructed)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see from the test, the reconstructed `timedelta` object is the same as the original one, even when it is initialized with an arbitrary number if `milliseconds` and `microseconds`.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert a string to timedelta.

```
import datetime

td = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)

# timedelta to string
s = str(td) # 2:00:00

# string to timedelta
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(s,"%H:%M:%S")
td2 = datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)
```

Comment: From the source code for `datetime` (which appears to be available at https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/datetime/datetime.py), it would appear from the `__str__` method definition that there are some special changes if the `timedelta` includes days or microseconds. It looks like Will Roberts, the author of [pytimeparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytimeparse/1.1.5), has (painstakingly) covered all these cases.

Answer (score 0):

How about use pickle? You may refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html
Serialize the time delta object, and get back the object later.

```
import pickle 

tdi = pickle.dumps(td)

tdo = pickle.loads(tdi) # will have the time delta object 

str(tdo)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer to have the representation as a human-readable string rather than a sequence of bytes.