# Difference between timestamps in Arrow

Tags: python, datetime, arrow-python

How would I get Arrow to return the difference in hours between two timestamps?

Here's what I have:

```
difference = arrow.now() - arrow.get(p.create_time())
print(difference.hour)
```

`p.create_time()` being the timestamp of the create time of a currently running process.

Returns:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Edit: I don't want the total time in all three formats, I want it as a remainder eg. "3 days, 4 hours, 36 minutes" not "3 days, 72 hours, 4596 minutes"

Comment: Close to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472.

Comment: @alecxe please see my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [formatting python timedelta objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906926/formatting-python-timedelta-objects)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Given 2 dates that are formatted from a string to `arrow` type.

```
>>> date_1 = arrow.get('2015-12-23 18:40:48','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
>>> date_2 = arrow.get('2017-11-15 13:18:20','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
>>> diff = date_2 - date_1
```

The difference is a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) data type.

```
>>> print type(diff)
<type 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

And results in:

```
>>> print diff
692 days, 18:37:32
```

To get it formatted such that you would have `D days, H hours, M minutes, S seconds` you would get the days separately, and then using `divmod` function get the other information.

```
>>> days = diff.days # Get Day 
>>> hours,remainder = divmod(diff.seconds,3600) # Get Hour 
>>> minutes,seconds = divmod(remainder,60) # Get Minute & Second
```

The result would be:

```
>>> print days, " Days, ", hours, " Hours, ", minutes, " Minutes, ", seconds, " Second"
692  Days,  18  Hours,  37  Minutes,  32  Second
```