# Pandas - Converting Derived Datetime to Integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, 'df', where there is an original column with dates in datetime format. I set a hard date as a variable:

```
 hard_date = datetime.date(2013, 5, 2)
```

I then created a new column in my df with the difference between the values in the date column and the hard_date...

```
df['days_from'] = df['date'] - hard_date
```

This produced a good output. for instance, when I print the first cell in the new column it shows:

```
print (df['days_from'].iloc[0])

28 days 00:00:00
```

But now I want to convert the new column to just the number of days as an integer. I thought about just taking the first 2 characters, but many of the values are negative, so I am seeking a better route.

Any thoughts on an efficient way to convert the column to just the integer of the days?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `.days`? datetime [timedeltas](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) let you look at each piece separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a timedelta to days, hours and minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the [`.dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) accessor and `.days` attribute on the timedeltas.

```
df.days_from = df.days_from.dt.days
```