# Extract hr part from datetime.timedelta Python

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have time record like '7:30:00' (type= datetime.timedelta)

I need to extract `hr` part, example '7'. 
how can i do it?

Comment: Check out this one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a timedelta to days, hours and minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes)