# Convert Days and Time (Hours x Minutes x Seconds) to Time only

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a Dataframe in which I am making the difference between two different dates to get the difference in Hours and Minutes, for example:

```
 start_date = '2018-07-03 16:03:00'
 data_final = '2018-07-05 00:00:00'
 duration = data_final - start_date
```

The result I'm looking for is **'31: 57: 00 '**, or the total time difference between the two dates. But the result I have is: **'1 day, 7:57:00'** (Every 24 hours it writes as 1 day).

I tried converting it to an XMinutesHours format with the statement:

```
print (datetime.datetime.strptime (duration, "%H:%M:%S"))
```

But I got the error:

> ValueError: time data '1 day, 7:57:00' does not match format '% H:%
>   M:% S'

Any idea?

Comment: check for spaces after "%" sign

Comment: already checked friend. But didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to calculate the equivalent in hours, minutes and seconds,
you could implement a function to get this value, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_duration(duration):
    hours = int(duration / 3600)
    minutes = int(duration % 3600 / 60)
    seconds = int((duration % 3600) % 60)
    return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)

format_str = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
start_date_str = '2018-07-03 16:03:00'
end_date_str = '2018-07-05 00:00:00'

start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_str, format_str)
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date_str, format_str)
duration = (end_date - start_date).total_seconds()

print(get_duration(duration))
```

Comment: Excellent Hydex, it worked for me, thanks for your time bro!. I just had to convert it before, with the function that i added in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a `datetime.timedelta` object, which is what you get from the subtration of two `datetime.datetime` objects. This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes).

On a side note, it looks like you're trying to use `strptime` when you really want to use `strftime`. `strptime` **p**arses a string and turns it into a `datetime.datetime` object (hence the **p**), whereas `strftime` **f**ormats a `datetime.datetime` object as a string (hence the **f**).

Answer (score 0):

First covert the columns to datetime fields using pd.to_datetime.

lets say you have a dataframe df with the column start_time.

```
import pandas as pd

df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time']
df['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time']

df['time_diff'] = (df.end_time - df.start_time) #gets the time in hours
```

if you want to convert it to hours use:

```
df['time_diff'] = df['time_diff'].dt.total_seconds()/(3600.0)
```

But this wont give exactly in the H:M:S format.