# How to convert from days and hours to just hours?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have only found question [Convert Days and Time (Hours x Minutes x Seconds) to Time only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197654/convert-days-and-time-hours-x-minutes-x-seconds-to-time-only) on stackoverflow and that seems like it would help me out but it doesn't seem to totally apply to what I'm doing.

I'm writing a wage tracking program and need it to give me the total sum of all hour input. I've got a much smaller and abridged form of it to just work on this one aspect. It saves a lot of time as the main program requires all the individual start and end times to be input by the user. It is currently showing `2 days, 22:00:00` as on output whereas I ideally would prefer it to show `70:00`, showing only the hours and minutes and getting rid of the unneeded second part.

```py
import datetime


def time_diff(a, b):  # Calculates time difference between start and finish
    return b - a


start = '10:00'
mon_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
finish = '20:00'
mon_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(finish, '%H:%M')
mon_hours = time_diff(mon_start, mon_fin)

start = '10:00'
tue_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
finish = '20:00'
tue_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(finish, '%H:%M')
tue_hours = time_diff(tue_start, tue_fin)

start = '10:00'
wed_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
finish = '20:00'
wed_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(finish, '%H:%M')
wed_hours = time_diff(wed_start, wed_fin)

start = '10:00'
thu_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
finish = '20:00'
thu_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(finish, '%H:%M')
thu_hours = time_diff(thu_start, thu_fin)

start = '10:00'
fri_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
finish = '20:00'
fri_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(finish, '%H:%M')
fri_hours = time_diff(fri_start, fri_fin)

start = '10:00'
sat_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
finish = '20:00'
sat_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(finish, '%H:%M')
sat_hours = time_diff(sat_start, sat_fin)

start = '10:00'
sun_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
finish = '20:00'
sun_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(finish, '%H:%M')
sun_hours = time_diff(sun_start, sun_fin)

total_hours = mon_hours + tue_hours + wed_hours + thu_hours + fri_hours + sat_hours + sun_hours
print(total_hours)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
def time_diff(a, b):  # Calculates time difference between start and finish
    return b - a
```

if `a` is `datetime.datetime` and `b` is `datetime.datetime` `return` `datetime.timedelta` object. You can use its `.total_seconds` method to get value in second, which then you might use for further calculations, for example

```
import datetime
total = datetime.timedelta(days=3,minutes=10)
total_minutes = int(total.total_seconds()//60)
hours, minutes = total_minutes // 60, total_minutes % 60
print(hours, minutes)  # 72 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this print at the end:

```
print(
    "{}:{:02d}".format(
        total_hours.days * 24 + total_hours.seconds // 3600,
        (total_hours.seconds // 60) % 60,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions will work, but just wanted to share something from my side as well.

**Code:**

```py
seconds = time_diff(a, b).total_seconds()


def convert(seconds):
    mins, secs = divmod(int(seconds), 60)
    hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
    return f'{hours:02d}:{mins:02d}:{secs:02d}'


print(convert(seconds))    # Will print in HH:MM:SS format
```