# Django DateTimeField() casuing TypeError ('datetime.timedelta' object is not callable)

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to get differenc of two Datetiemfield in Djago. I have tried overriding the default save() but still getting error.

models.py

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    ad_start = models.DateTimeField() 
    ad_end = models.DateTimeField()
    ad_duration = models.IntegerField()

@property
def get_time_diff(self):
    timediff = self.ad_end - self.ad_start
    return timediff
    #return relativedelta(self.ad_end, self.ad_start)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.ad_duration = self.get_time_diff()
    super(Sample, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class SampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Sample
    exclude = ("submitted", 'ad_duration', "list_date" )
    widgets = {
        'ad_start': DatePickerInput(), 
        'ad_end': DatePickerInput(),
    }
```

Error

```
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:'datetime.timedelta' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two changes required in your code.

First, you need to remove `@property` from method `get_time_diff`. Because you can't call a property method via `()`. Or, you can still keep the property method ,but don't call it in save function, for example like this:  `self.ad_duration = self.get_time_diff`

Second, you need to update the model field to [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) to store the time delta object created in `get_time_diff`. Like this:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
        ad_start = models.DateTimeField() 
        ad_end = models.DateTimeField()
        ad_duration = models.DurationField()


    def get_time_diff(self):
        timediff = self.ad_end - self.ad_start
        return timediff


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ad_duration = self.get_time_diff()
        super(Sample, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or you can get the total seconds from `get_time_diff` and store it in `ad_duration` field(which will be a float field).

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    ad_start = models.DateTimeField() 
    ad_end = models.DateTimeField()
    ad_duration = models.FloatField()

    def get_time_diff(self):
        timediff = self.ad_end - self.ad_start
        return timediff.total_seconds()  # returns value in seconds
```

Comment: DurationField() has created bigint(20) type in mysql database. the stored value in database is "86400000000".  And in django admin interface the value is shown as "1 00:00:00". How can i show it in admin interface as Day.(e.g. 1, 2 )

Comment: You can create a [read only method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) in admin site, and show the day following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes).