# datetime.timedelta dates difference result converting to all days or minutes

Tags: python, python-datetime

How can I make my datetime.timedelta result **shows all in days or minutes**?

My expected output is:

```
minute left: 7023 min
days left: 5.002 day
```

My code:

```
aaa = "2017-09/19 07:11:00"
bbb = "2017-09/24 07:14:00"

result = parser.parse(bbb) - parser.parse(aaa)

print(result)
print(type(result))
```

The output:

```
5 days, 0:03:00         
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a timedelta to days, hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: that do help, thanks, now I solve my problem, appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert to seconds and then convert seconds to minutes/hours

```
result = parser.parse( bbb) -parser.parse( aaa)

seconds = result.total_seconds()
minutes = seconds/60
hours = minutes/60
```

Answer (score -1):

solved code:  (thanks for @Joran Beasley contributing )

```js
from dateutil import parser
import datetime,time
aaa= "2017-09/19 07:11:00"
bbb= "2017-09/24 07:14:00"

result = parser.parse( bbb) -parser.parse( aaa)
seconds = result.total_seconds()

minutes = seconds/60
hours = minutes/60

print(result)
print(type(result))
print(minutes)
print(hours)
```

The  result output:

> 5 days, 0:03:00
> <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
> 7203.0
> 120.05

Comment: Please do not include images of code or link to images of code in questions or answers.

Comment: Hi @Chris , I just removed image