# Find previous calendar day in python

Tags: python, file, datetime, date, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I subtract a day from a python date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date)

I have a set of files that I'm saving by date, year_month_day.txt format.  I need to open the previous day's text file for some processing.  How do I find the previous day's date in python?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here you go:

```
>>> print datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1)
>>> 2010-06-19
```

Answer (score 7):

Say you start with a string `'2010_05_1'`.  Then the similar string for the previous day is:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = '2010_05_1'
>>> theday = datetime.date(*map(int, s.split('_')))
>>> prevday = theday - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> prevday.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
'2010_04_30'
>>>
```

Of course you'll encapsulate all of this into one handy function!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html).

```
import datetime
print (datetime.date(year, month, day) - datetime.timedelta(1)).isoformat()
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

1. Convert the year/month/day to a number.
2. Subtract 1 from that number.
3. Convert the number to year/month/day.

You will find the `localtime` and `mktime` functions from the [`time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) module helpful.

(Also, since the `time` module deals with seconds, you would subtract 86400 instead of 1.)