# Python Threading Timer and Event objects

Tags: python, multithreading, events, timer

**code:**

```
from threading import Timer, Event
from time import sleep

def hello(e):
    print e
    print 'Inside......'
    while True:
        if e.isSet():
            print "hello_world"
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = Event()
    t = Timer(1, hello(e,))
    t.start()
    print e.isSet()
    sleep(2)
    e.set()
    print e.isSet()
```

**Output:**

```
 [root@localhost ~]# python test_event.py 
<threading._Event object at 0x7f440cbbc310>
Inside......
```

In the above code, I am trying to understand the `Timer and, Event`  objects from python. If I run the above code, the `Timer` invokes the function `hello()` and it runs indefinitely. The main thread is not executing the line next to `t.start()`. What am I missing here??

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [threading.Timer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578652/threading-timer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,

```
t = Timer(1, hello(e,))
```

Instead of passing arguments to the thread, you are calling the function before creating the thread. `hello(e,)` calls the function which waits for the event `e` to set. Since it's stuck in an infinite loop here and doesn't return from the function `hello`, the thread creation is not happening and `e` is never set.

Just change it to a valid thread creation:

```
t = Timer(1, hello, [e])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it with clarity.