# Auto run python web-scraping program

Tags: python, ubuntu, web-scraping

I intend to do web-scraping of a particular website to get the data regularly. I want this python program to be run every day a couple of times automatically. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?
Ubuntu is my OS

Comment: It is possible what OS are you running?

Comment: how can i do it. my OS is ubuntu

Comment: you could/should use `cron`

Comment: is there any problem in 17 19 * * * ~/Desktop python hello.py
 in cron? @dm03514

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have options that I can think of. You could have your python code do it all like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090893/1165441

Or if you would like to set up a cron job and execute your script that way here are instructions for Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

In my opinion using a cron job is cleaner because of separations of concerns, but the quick and dirty way would work as well.

Comment: I think cron is the simplest answer here.

Comment: i am using this in cron but it wont work ? 17 19 * * * ~/Desktop python hello.py

Comment: @user3415869 I honestly haven't used cron in a while so I couldn't tell you without looking it up and you could do the same.

Comment: its okay. i have one question. so the cron will be executing the program even my pc is turned off?

Comment: @user3415869 no. You can't execute code on a machine that is turned off.