# Listing network systems under a domain using python

Tags: python, networking, python-2.x

I am planing to develop an application using python 2.6 which should scan my company network (which is a domain ex: www.xyz.com) and list all systems. Our systems contains both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple script I just made for you. Install Nmap on a Linux machine and make a chron tab to run this script once a day or something and it will output that XML file that is referenced in the script.

```
import os
os.system("nmap -A -O -oX XML.XML target.whatever")
```

[Click here to learn more about nmap](https://nmap.org/)

[click here to learn about crontabs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)

Comment: does nmap works on windows also. i am trying for a a multi-platform code. For time being Windows and LInux

Comment: Yes it does work. :) Heres a link, https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html

Comment: And instead of using cron you could do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088037/python-script-to-do-something-at-the-same-time-every-day