# Scheduling a simple notification script in Python to run every hour

Tags: python, datetime, scheduled-tasks

I'm totally new to Python.

I just wrote this simple script that prints a message on my desktop:

```
from plyer import notification
notification.notify(
title="HI MATTEO!",
message="Here's the notification to be sent every hour!",
timeout=10
)
```

[Here's the screenshot of the notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/877yg.jpg)

I'd like to know if there's a way to **run this notification every hour** (or at a given time)

Thanks so much

Matteo Fossati

Comment: You should decide whether you want to have a Python program which runs continuously and performs certain actions at certain times, or if you want the operating system to run your program at certain times (and your program then performs the action and exits). If the latter, then you need to say which operating system you are using. For example, under Linux you would use `crontab`.

Comment: I'd like to write a script inside the same program which makes the program itself run at certain times, so the first one

Comment: Unfortunately I don't 100% understand your reply, but if you want the first option, then it sounds like Roy2012's answer should give you what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088037/python-script-to-do-something-at-the-same-time-every-day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the `schedule` package (https://pypi.org/project/schedule/).

Then, run something like:

```
schedule.every().hour.do(my_notification)
...
while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Great! It works! Is there also a way to run the same program when the IDE is closed? Thx Matteo

Comment: sure. Just open a terminal, and run 'python my_prog.py'.

Comment: BTW - if this answers your question, it would be great if you could accept my answer for future generations.

Comment: ok, done. Another issue: I tried to run the program from the command line in Windows but it throws an error

Comment: C:\Users\matfo>python C:\Users\matfo\PycharmProjects\notifica.py
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\matfo\PycharmProjects\notifica.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: are you certain that the file exists in this location? Try copying it to another location (e.g. c:\temp, and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: I tried again and it works now (seems like I wrote the wrong path). Thank you very much!

Comment: Great to hear :)