# Scheduling multiple schedules

Tags: python, schedule

I would like to start my code at the start of every hour I have tried using the minutes function of schedule however, the start time of the next process is dependent upon the end of the previous process and with the code I am trying to process the delay accumulates pretty quickly hence, I am trying this method instead. All help is appreciated. Thanks.

The code:

```
import schedule 
import time
schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("01:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("02:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("03:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("04:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("05:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("07:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("08:34").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("09:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("11:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("13:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("14:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("15:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("16:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("17:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("18:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("19:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("20:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("22:00").do(consolidated)
schedule.every().day.at("23:00").do(consolidated)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088037/python-script-to-do-something-at-the-same-time-every-day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

Comment: Yes it actually does thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `schedule` package has an option for doing a task every hour:

```
import schedule
import time

schedule.every().hour.do(consolidated)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```