# How to make this scraping periodically append to a csv file?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I made this little script as I'm learning to scrape with bs4 and selenium and I want to collect periodic date of weather into a csv file but I am quite new and I don't know where to begin.

Can someone point me in the right direction on to how to make this run every date and append data? For now, I run and it just makes the header and the second row.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from csv import writer

```
url = 'https://weather.com/es-US/tiempo/10dias/l/468124beb45cd6817ec6a1da2675f104fede76a75ba7ce08c9ae21606ac208b5'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/thras/Desktop/Chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')



degrees = soup.find('span', class_="DailyContent--temp--3d4dn").text
humidity = soup.find('span', class_="Wind--windWrapper--3aqXJ DailyContent--value--37sk2").text
wind = soup.find('span', class_="DailyContent--temp--3d4dn").text
date = soup.find('span', class_="DailyContent--daypartDate--2A3Wi").text

info = [degrees, humidity, wind, date]

with open('weather.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    mywriter = writer(f)
    header = ('Degrees', 'Humidity', 'Wind', 'Date')
    mywriter.writerow(header)
    mywriter.writerow([degrees, humidity, wind, date])
    
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

To schedule the python script to run it every day you could either use a builtin task scheduler of your os or you could schedule it inside the script itself. Here you could use the python library `schedule`. You can see an example here: [stackoverflow schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393162)

To add the row to your existing csv, you just have to open it in append mode.

```
import csv   
fields=['A','B']
with open('weather.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```

Comment: I actually realized I can't append it for some reason, could you show me how would you do it please?

Comment: I added a small example of writing csv in append mode. The difference ist mostly the 'a' instead of the 'w', as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is to schedual your programm to be executed every day.
If you are on MacOs or Linux you can use **crontab**.

If you are on Windows you can use Windows **Task Scheduler**
search on the interent how they work.

Comment: I'm on MacOs but you're right, didn't think of that! Thanks