# How to generate range of dates: every day of a given year?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I want to iterate all the days in a given year: so it will generate a datetime object for the 1st of January, through all the other days (including Feb 29 - if it exists for that year) to the 31st of December.

How can I do this ?

I was trying this:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime( 2015, 1, 1 )
start_date = startdate + 1
```

But then realized you can't just add one (one what?) like this- you have to add on a timedelta (of one day) to do this.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @MorganThrapp don't act as this is something straight forward in Python, it isn't, closest thing he **could've** found (which I don't consider "timedelta") is `someDatetime.replace(day=someDatetime.day+someNumber)` which a) throws `day is out of range for month` if `someNumber` is too high instead of automatically increasing the month and overflowing b) is super unintuitively named , if this'd be JavaScript, then OK, but here ........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def gen_days( year ):
    start_date=datetime( year, 1, 1 )
    end_date=datetime( year, 12, 31 )
    d=start_date
    dates=[ start_date ]
    while d < end_date:
        d += timedelta(days=1)
        dates.append( d )
    return dates

if __name__=='__main__':
    d=gen_days( 2015 )
    print len(d)
    d2=gen_days( 2016 ) # leap year
    print len(d2)
```

Sorry - was going to post some non-working code with my question, but I got it working more quickly than I thought (with help from this and others : [How to increment the day in datetime? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240458/how-to-increment-the-day-in-datetime-python))