# Add 1 day to my date in Python

Tags: python, date

I have the following date format:

```
year/month/day
```

In my task, I have to add only 1 day to this date. For example:

```
date = '2004/03/30'
function(date)
>'2004/03/31'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Using the `datetime` module?

Comment: `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` `date += timedelta(days=1)`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) from the standard library. Load the date string via [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), [use `timedelta` to add a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240458/how-to-increment-the-day-in-datetime-python), then use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to dump the date back to a string:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> s = '2004/03/30'
>>> date = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y/%m/%d")
>>> modified_date = date + timedelta(days=1)
>>> datetime.strftime(modified_date, "%Y/%m/%d")
'2004/03/31'
```

Comment: The last line may not be necessary, `modified_date` preserves its format after the 1 day is added