# Python: Add one day to custom date?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to add one day to custom date(in string). Time format is `dd/mm/yyyy`

Sample input:

```
 '02/11/2020'
```

Output:

```
 '03/11/2020'
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add 1 day to my date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089765/add-1-day-to-my-date-in-python)

Comment: I have tried converting it to period. `pd.Period(var_name)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding 5 days to a date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-a-date-in-python)

Comment: `(datetime.strptime('02/11/2020', '%d/%m/%Y') + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = '02/11/2020'
old = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
new = old + timedelta(days=1)
new_date = new.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

print(new_date) # '03/11/2020'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime` module

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime.strptime("%d/%m/%Y", "02/11/2020")
end = start + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
```