# Python: Nested loops for renaming files with julian dates

Tags: python, nested-loops, julian-date

I have ~30,000 daily temperature rasters (.asc) from 1971-2070 which need to be renamed. They are currently named as follows: tasmax_0.asc, tasmax_1.asc,....,tasmax_32767.asc.

I need to rename them with the julian date and year (i.e., tasmax_1_1971.asc, tasmax_2_1971.asc,....,tasmax_365_2070.asc).

I know I need to use a nested loop with different counters: a julian day counter (which needs to be reset at the start of each year), and a year counter. I get easily confused with nested loops, especially where leap years would have 366 days instead of 365 and I have to reset the julian day counter every year.

I am using python 2.7

Any help with wrapping my head around writing this script would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240458/how-to-increment-the-day-in-datetime-python). You can solve your problem without any nested loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for:

```
import os
filex = 0
year = 1971
while filex < 32768:
    if (( year%400 == 0)or (( year%4 == 0 ) and ( year%100 != 0))):
        days = 366
    else:
        days = 365
    current_day = 1
    while current_day <= days:
        os.rename(("tasmax_" + str(filex) + ".asc"),(("tasmax_" + str(current_day) + str(year) + ".asc")))
        current_day = current_day + 1
        filex = filex + 1
    year = year + 1
```

a counter for the file number, the days in the year, the current day, and the current year.

to rename the file im using

```
os.rename(oldfilename, newfilename)
```

but use whatever you would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

This example just prints out `1_1971`, `2_1971`, etc.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

day = date(1971, 1, 1) #1 Jan 1971
step = timedelta(1)    #1 day
curr_year = day.year
count = 1

while day.year <= 2070:
    print("{}_{}".format(count, curr_year))
    day += step
    count += 1
    if day.year != curr_year:
        count = 1
        curr_year = day.year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.

```
import os
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime(1971, 1, 1) # January 1, 1971

for fname in os.listdir("date_folder"): # Iterate through filenames
    num_days = fname.split("_")[1] # Check number of days from start
    cur_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=num_days) # Add number of days to start
    os.rename(fname, "tasmax_{0}_{1}".format(cur_date.day, cur_date.year)) # Reformat filename
```

This assumes that all the files are in a directory by themselves.