# date and time aware datetime object in python

Tags: python, datetime

What I want to do is obtaining a new `datetime` object using python `datetime` replace() method.
this works fine for most cases, however let's say the day is 31 of January 2019 23:00 PM and i executed:

```
datetime.now().replace(hour=datetime.now().hour + 1 )
```

What i want to have back is a new `datetime` object with hour set to 0 ,day Set to 1 and month set 2
I am new to python if the question has an obvious answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increment a datetime by one day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240458/how-to-increment-a-datetime-by-one-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need `datetime.timedelta`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

print( datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1))
```