# How to iterate from a custom day in the past to today?

Tags: python

I need to iterate through all the days from a custom day to now. I need all the correct day not just the count of the days.

For example, I enter 10 for month and 2018 for year. I need to get:

```
2018-10-01
2018-10-02
...
2018-10-31
2018-11-01
2018-11-02
...
2019-05-21
```

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240458/how-to-increment-a-datetime-by-one-day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print all day-dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274267/print-all-day-dates-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample uses `for loop`. But, I try to use recursion.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def getdate(date):
    print (date)
    if date == date.today(): return
    getdate(date+timedelta(1))

start_date = date(2018, 1, 1)    
getdate(start_date)
```

Comment: recursion is more expansive then iteration + you might incur a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error.
So I would not agree that it is necessarily the better code.
https://www.quora.com/In-Python-which-is-more-efficient-to-use-recursion-or-iteration

Comment: @ohlr Thank you for the advice. I agree with you that it is not the better code. But, I think Recursive code could be good style to reduce side effect and to make simple code.

Answer (score 1):

[How to increment a datetime by one day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240458/how-to-increment-a-datetime-by-one-day)

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html

```
date = datetime.datetime(2007,12,5)
while date != datetime.date.today(): 
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a **dataframe** from **pandas**, the `date_range` function does all the work for you [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). The `pd.datetime.now()` method gives you the current date [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.now.html)

Here one example:

```
def get_df_days_to_now(year, month, day = 1):
    date_start = "%4d/%d/%d" % (year, month, day)
    date_end = pd.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    return pd.date_range(start=date_start, end=date_end, freq="D")

print(get_df_days_to_now(2019, 5))
# DatetimeIndex(['2019-05-01', '2019-05-02', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-04',
#                '2019-05-05', '2019-05-06', '2019-05-07', '2019-05-08',
#                '2019-05-09', '2019-05-10', '2019-05-11', '2019-05-12',
#                '2019-05-13', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-15', '2019-05-16',
#                '2019-05-17', '2019-05-18', '2019-05-19', '2019-05-20',
#                '2019-05-21', '2019-05-22'],
#                     dtype = 'datetime64[ns]', freq = 'D')
```