# How to obtain the next day's date based on user inputted date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I have the following code:

```
def dates_sec():
    START_DATE = str(input('Enter start date in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S format: '))
    END_DATE = str(input('Enter end date in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S format: '))

    try:
        START_DATE = datetime.datetime.strptime(START_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        END_DATE = datetime.datetime.strptime(END_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        start_date = START_DATE.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        end_date = END_DATE.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        print('Dates accepted!')
        return start_date, end_date
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")

SD, ED = dates_sec()
```

Here, I take 2 dates as input from the user. Now, Based on what the `END_DATE` is inputted by the user, I would like to generate a new variable named `NEXT_DATE` which contains the next day's date in `%Y%m%d` form.

**Example:**

If I input `START_DATE` as `2018-07-01 00:00:00`

and

the `END_DATE` as `2018-07-01 00:00:00`,

then the varibles `SD` & `ED`are `20180701` & `20180731` respectively.

Now, based on the `END_DATE`, the `NEXT_DATE` must be `2018-08-01 00:00:00` and must be returned as `20180801`.

I would like to know how can I do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increment a datetime by one day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240458/how-to-increment-a-datetime-by-one-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
NEXT_DATE = END_DATE + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
next_date = NEXT_DATE.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'deltatime'`. Do you mean to say `timedelta(days = 1)` ?

Comment: Yes. My bad. Fixed my answer.

Comment: It throws the following error now: `TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta`

Comment: On which line? What throws the `TypeError`?

Comment: Error is thrown here: `next_date = end_date + datetime.datetime.timedelta(days=1)

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'`

Comment: Yes, because `end_date` you've already converted to string. You need to use `END_DATE`

Comment: Oh yes. My bad. Got it. Thanks. I'll accept the answer