# Loop with function: how to update date field?

Tags: python, loops

I would need to iterate one day a time the following functions which contains this parameter as follows:

```
start_date=input("\nStart date: mm/dd/yyyy ")
end_date=start_date

fun(start_date,end_date)
```

where start_date should be a date chosen by user in that format. End_date has to be equal to start date, as I am interested in one-day search. However, I would need to repeat this research also for the other days.
My code is currently doing the following:

- enter a start_date. It is my start date. For example: 08/22/2020
- then set end_date equal to start_date. Then it is equal to 08/22/2020
- apply this function to look for information in 08/22/2020;
- when it finishes (it is included in my function), please update the date, increasing by one (i.e. 08/23/2020);
- repeat the search in 08/23/2020

I am having difficulties to look for next day, also because there might be months with 30, 31 and 28/29 days.

Could you please tell me how could I update my code?

Comment: Refer to [How to increment a datetime by one day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240458/how-to-increment-a-datetime-by-one-day).

Comment: Seems that the question in principle is asking for calculation using strings. But really, you ought to convert your dates into `datetime.datetime` objects immediately after reading in (see `datetime.datetime.strptime`), do all the manipulation in that form, and only convert back to strings when needed for output purposes (see `strftime` method).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment a datetime by one day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240458/how-to-increment-a-datetime-by-one-day)

Comment: Specifically to convert to datetime: `dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('08/22/2020', '%m/%d/%Y')`, to convert back again: `dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`, and to do the calculation, see the link that a couple of people have posted.

Comment: Refer timedelta class. Its sole purpose is to add, subtract days/h/m/s to datetime objects.

Comment: Use a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
```

i am using generator to hide/abstract iteration over the range of dates.