# How to retrieve records from past weeks in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I am having trouble in django on how to retrieve data from last week (not 7 days ago). Using `date.isocalendar()[1]` would be great. However Some stackoverflow browsing lead me to no satisfactory results.

Whatsoever, I could do without portability and use mysql's `INTERVAL` function. This is the query I want to make using django's ORM.

`SELECT id, user_id, CAST(timestamp AS Date), WEEK(timestamp,3), WEEK(CURDATE(), 3) FROM main_userstats WHERE week(timestamp, 3) = WEEK(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK ), 3)`

how can I do this using the `extra` function in django (if it's not possible to do in any other simpler way)?

Comment: I'm just saying, this used to frustrate me a lot in Django and I had a choice to switch to Ruby, so I did and haven't looked back:

Instead of: `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=timezone.now().date()-timedelta(days=7))`

You write: `Entry.where( :pub_date.gte => 7.days.ago )`

The same syntax also applies to both SQL type databases and MongoDB too which is fantastic.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I assume what you are looking for are all the entries that belong to the same calendar week of the previous week.

This should do the trick:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField([...])
```

To get the objects:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
some_day_last_week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)
monday_of_last_week = some_day_last_week - timedelta(days=(some_day_last_week.isocalendar()[2] - 1))
monday_of_this_week = monday_of_last_week + timedelta(days=7)
Entry.objects.filter(created_at__gte=monday_of_last_week, created_at__lt=monday_of_this_week)
```

Note that I added 7 days to get the monday of the this week instead of adding 6 days to get the sunday of last week and that I used created_at__lt=monday_of_this_week (instead of __lte=). I did that because if your pub_date was a DateTimeField, it wouldn't include the sunday objects since the time is 00:00:00 when using now().date().

This could easily be adjusted to consider Sunday as the first day of the week instead, but isocalendar() considers it the last, so I went with that.

If using Django < 1.4 use the following:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
some_day_last_week = date.today() - timedelta(days=7)
```

instead of:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
some_day_last_week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)
```

Answer (score 10):

Look at the the [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) method of Django ORM.

Basic example:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  pub_date = models.DateField([...])

Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2006)
```

But you can do more complex queries with filter like:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=datetime.now())
```

As you can see, you can use `datetime` and other python libraries to define specific dates. Look at the documentation for [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) to see which posibilities you have.

In your case you could do something like this ([inspired by this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date)):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d=date.today()-timedelta(days=7)
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=d)
```

I'm not a 100% sure if this lookup will work, but it is the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use `filter` method. And I also know that although I can filter by year or month, I cannot filter by week. I also want to avoid using date ranges.

Comment: What do you mean by "week"? Do you simply mean the last 7 days or do you mean the last week in the calendar?

Comment: I mean previous calendar week. which is why I also mentioned that `datetime.idocalendar()[1]` would be great to use.

Comment: Have you tried `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=datetime.idocalendar()[1])`?

Comment: it doesn't work. `ValidationError: [u"'26' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]`

Comment: My suggestion would be to write yourself a little helper method which turns/parses the result of `datetime.isocalendar()` to a date with `time.strptime`. Then you could use `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=my_little_helper_method())`.

Comment: The urls are deprecated. Use this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#date

Answer (score 0):

You can query the data by week number week and iso_year

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.today()
week = date.strftime("%V")

Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__week=week)
from django.utils.the timezone import now
year, week, _ = now().isocalendar()

Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__iso_year=year, pub_date__week=week)
```