# How to get yesterday in python

Tags: python

To get now, I can do:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

How would I get 24 hours ago?

```
now - 24 hrs. ?
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use `timedelta`:

```
datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: Nice of you to answer your own question... was anything wrong with using `timedelta(days=1)` though?

Comment: It needs to be corrected. It should be: `datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)`. And please don't forget `import datetime` first

Comment: in regions where daylight saving is used not all days are 24 hours.

Answer (score 11):

you could use:

```
datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-1)
```

[Get yesterday's date in Python, DST-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344710/get-yesterdays-date-in-python-dst-safe)

this will help with formatting:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-get-current-date-time-in-python/