# django filter one day old data from model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

model as,

```
class some(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
    ...
    ...
```

I want one day old records from `some` model. So I have tried,

```
some.objects.filter(created_on__gte=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

It does not seems much impressive way to filter, any another approach ?

Comment: What part of it do you not like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get yesterday's date in Python, DST-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344710/get-yesterdays-date-in-python-dst-safe)

Comment: should not it be `__lte` ? and should it be exactly one day old or one  day and more ?

Comment: @Sayse I dont like `created_on__gte=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)` this part. Can I reduce it ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to calculate `yesterday` anyway.

```
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

If you are using Django 1.9, you can use:

```
some.objects.filter(created_on__date=yesterday)
```

Otherwise you are doing it right.