# Adding a timedelta of +1 day to a date with pytz in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, datetime, pytz

I'm trying to add a timedelta of +1 days to my datetime object using:

```
.timedelta(days=1)
```

With:

```
datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/London')).strftime("%d%m%Y")`
```

But for some reason, it's not working as it doesn't allow it to be put anywhere in that line.

I've also tried:

```
GMTDAY = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/London'))
GMTDAY = str(GMTDAY + timedelta(days=1))
GMTDAY = datetime(int(GMTDAY)).strftime("%d%m%Y")
```

But that returns:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2016-04-28 02:50:52.436000+01:00'

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to solve it?

EDIT:

It's not a duplicate because this one is specifically about doing it with pytz, it's easy to do it without pytz.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add delta to python datetime.time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time)

Comment: After GMTDAY = str(GMTDAY + timedelta(days=1)) you converted GMTDAY to a string; it is not really clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: related: [Get yesterday's date in Python, DST-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15345272/4279)

Comment: related: [How can I subtract a day from a Python date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441147/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpreted correctly what you are trying to do, try something like:

```
GMTDAY = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/London'))
GMTDAY += timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = GMTDAY.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print(tomorrow)
```

Output:

```
28-04-2016
```

Comment: I turned it into a string based on some other stackoverflow posts, is it possible to condesne that into a single line bit of code?

Comment: @Ryflex: if the `+DAY`  moves the date across a DST boundary then you have to use `pytz_timezone.normalize()` method to get the correct local time.